# Can't get Python to import from a different folder

Tags: python, python-2.x

I can't seem to get Python to import a module in a subfolder. I get the error when I try to create an instance of the class from the imported module, but the import itself succeeds. Here is my directory structure:

```
Server
    -server.py
    -Models
        --user.py
```

Here's the contents of server.py:

```
from sys import path
from os import getcwd
path.append(getcwd() + "\\models") #Yes, i'm on windows
print path
import user

u=user.User() #error on this line
```

And user.py:

```
class User(Entity):
    using_options(tablename='users')

    username = Field(String(15))
    password = Field(String(64))
    email    = Field(String(50))
    status   = Field(Integer)
    created  = Field(DateTime)
```

The error is:
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'User'

Comment: Can you paste the error message?

Comment: Added a 2.x tag because the answers here describe solving the problem by adding an `__init__.py`, which **is not necessary** in 3.x. The issue here is not reproducible in 3.x (of course, the `print` statement would have to be updated to a function call).

Answer (score 170, accepted):

I believe you need to create a file called `__init__.py` in the Models directory so that python treats it as a module.

Then you can do:

```
from Models.user import User
```

You can include code in the `__init__.py` (for instance initialization code that a few different classes need) or leave it blank.  But it must be there.

Comment: Thanks, I had never heard of packages before this.

Comment: Actually, when importing Python treats blah.py and and blah/__init__.py exactly the same.

Comment: That was unobvious... And I say to myself: RTFM FMF

Comment: Note that this won't work if you're running server.py from another directory.

Comment: what if server.py is in another folder?

Comment: It seems to be that in Python 3.8.6 that `__init__.py` file is not necessary. It's just about importing directly what you need (using for example, `from folder.file import *`)

Answer (score 28):

You have to create `__init__.py` on the `Models` subfolder. The file may be empty. It defines a package.

Then you can do:

```
from Models.user import User
```

Read all about it in python tutorial, [here](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#packages).

There is also a good article about file organization of python projects [here](http://jcalderone.livejournal.com/39794.html).

Comment: What if the file is NOT empty?

Answer (score 13):

> import user
>
> u=user.User() #error on this line

Because of the lack of __init__ mentioned above, you would expect an ImportError which would make the problem clearer.

You don't get one because 'user' is also an existing module in the standard library. Your import statement grabs that one and tries to find the User class inside it; that doesn't exist and only then do you get the error.

It is generally a good idea to make your import absolute:

```
import Server.Models.user
```

to avoid this kind of ambiguity. Indeed from Python 2.7 'import user' won't look relative to the current module at all.

If you really want relative imports, you can have them explicitly in Python 2.5 and up using the somewhat ugly syntax:

```
from .user import User
```

Answer (score 13):

The right way to import a module located on a parent folder, when you don't have a standard package structure, is:

```
import os, sys
CURRENT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(CURRENT_DIR))
```

(you can merge the last two lines but this way is easier to understand).

This solution is cross-platform and is general enough to need not modify in other circumstances.

Answer (score 8):

You're missing __init__.py. From the Python tutorial:

> The __init__.py files are required to
>   make Python treat the directories as
>   containing packages; this is done to
>   prevent directories with a common
>   name, such as string, from
>   unintentionally hiding valid modules
>   that occur later on the module search
>   path. In the simplest case,
>   __init__.py can just be an empty file, but it can also execute initialization
>   code for the package or set the
>   __all__ variable, described later.

Put an empty file named __init__.py in your Models directory, and all should be golden.

Answer (score 1):

how do you write out the parameters `os.path.dirname`.... command?

```
import os, sys
CURRENT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(CURRENT_DIR))
```

Answer (score 0):

My preferred way is to have __init__.py on every directory that contains modules that get used by other modules, and in the entry point, override sys.path as below:

```
def get_path(ss):
  return os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), ss)
sys.path += [
  get_path('Server'), 
  get_path('Models')
]
```

This makes the files in specified directories visible for import, and I can import user from Server.py.

Answer (score 0):

After going through the answers given by these contributors above - **Zorglub29, Tom, Mark, Aaron McMillin, lucasamaral, JoeyZhao, Kjeld Flarup, Procyclinsur, martin.zaenker, tooty44** and debugging the issue that I was facing I found out a different use case due to which I was facing this issue.
Hence adding my observations below for anybody's reference.

In my code I had a cyclic import of classes. For example:

```
src
 |-- utilities.py (has Utilities class that uses Event class)  
 |-- consume_utilities.py (has Event class that uses Utilities class)
 |-- tests
      |-- test_consume_utilities.py (executes test cases that involves Event class)
```

I got following error when I tried to execute **python -m pytest tests/test_utilities.py** for executing UTs written in test_utilities.py.

```
ImportError while importing test module '/Users/.../src/tests/test_utilities.py'.
Hint: make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names.
Traceback:
tests/test_utilities.py:1: in <module>
    from utilities import Utilities
...
...
E   ImportError: cannot import name 'Utilities'
```

The way I resolved the error was by re-factoring my code to move the functionality in cyclic import class so that I could remove the cyclic import of classes.

Note, I have `__init__.py` file in my '**src**' folder as well as '**tests**' folder and still was able to get rid of the '**ImportError**' just by re-factoring the code.

Following stackoverflow link provides much more details on [Circular dependency in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/894864/circular-dependency-in-python).

Answer (score 0):

Create start.py or with any name python file under the root directory and add the below lines

```
import os, sys
CURRENT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(CURRENT_DIR))
```

It will add your project root directory path in the system path variable. After adding, Python tries to search all files and libraries under this and the default path.

`Note: I have tested this locally. I don't think, it is required on the cloud.`

Answer (score -2):

I had the same issue and solved it by adding the project to PYTHONPATH.

Try:
export PYTHONPATH=path_to_your_project