# Python Circular import: solutions and best practice

Tags: python, import, ipython, circular-dependency, scientific-computing

I'm writing an application for **scientific data analysis** and I'm wondering what's the best way to structure the code to avoid (or address) the circular import problem. Currently  I'm using a mix of OO and procedural programming.

[Other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/894864/circular-dependency-in-pythonhttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/894864/circular-dependency-in-python) address this issue but in a more abstract way. Here I'm looking for a solution that is optimal in a more specific context.

I have a class `Container` defined in `DataLib.py` whose data consist in lists and/or arrays. With all methods and supporting functions `DataLib.py` is quite large (~1000 lines).

I have a second module `SelectionLib.py` (~400 lines) that contains only functions to "filter" the data in `Container` according to different criteria. These functions return new `Container` objects (with filtered data) and thus `SelectionLib.py` needs to import `Container` from `DataLib.py`. Note that, logically, these functions are "methods" for "Container", they are just implemented using python functions.

Now, I want to add some high level method to `Container` so that a complex analysis can be performed with a single function of method call. And by  "complex analysis" I mean an arbitrary number of `Container` methods call, local function (defined in DataLib.py) and filter functions (defined in`SelectionLib.py`).

So the problem is that `DataLib.py`  needs to import `SelectionLib.py` to use the filter functions, but `SelectionLib.py` already imports `DataLib.py`.

Right know my hackish solution is to run the two files with **run -i ...** from **IPython** so it is like having a big single file and I avoid the circular import. But at the same time this scripts are difficult to integrate for example in a GUI.

How do you suggest to solve this problem:

1. use pure OO and inheritance and split the object in 3: `CoreContainer` -> `SelectionContainer` -> `HighLevelContainer`
2. Restructuring the code (everything in one file?)
3. Some sort of [Import trickery](http://effbot.org/zone/import-confusion.htm) (put imports at the end)

Any feedback is appreciated!

Comment: Can't you avoid putting the high-level method on `Container` and let it be in a function on its own?(implemented in something like `data_tools.py` which would contain the high-level API). It would make your API more consistent(i.e. `Container` class provides "low-level" API, and other high-level API is implemented in functions) and it would avoid circular-imports.

Comment: Yes, this is a solution. I'm not sure the API would be be more consistent as "user" would still use both high-level and low-level class methods. And from the outside, without looking at the implementation, is not clear if a method is high- or low- level. And probably, just for execution, doesn't matter either. It's only when the user wants to read the implementation of a method that should look in two different files and see where it's defined.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the design.  Having a single container instance select from a list of instances and perform group operations  instances seems a bit wrong. Looks like a `Container` class should provide public methods, then a `Filter` class (selectionlib.py) should pick a list of the required Containers so an `Algorithm` class can manipulate the Containers through their public methods.  (i.e. option 1! :)  )

Comment: Thanks for the comment. However you probably misunderstand the implementation. `Container` contains already several lists and arrays representing the experimental data of an entire measurement. Would be inefficient to split every bit of information in a different object and using collections of objects as you suggested. Container has some public methods but many operations are performed directly accessing the attributes. For example if .time is a numpy array the user will use its methods. In other words `Container` is not an opaque object and known attributes/objects are part of the API.

Comment: If functions in `SelectionLib` are, as you say, "methods" for `Container`, it seems reasonable that `DataLib` imports `SelectionLib`, not the other way around.

Comment: @Zhenya, this is a very good suggestion. Due to the python duck-typing should work seamlessly even if functions in `SelectionLib` access methods and attributed of `Container`. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If functions in `SelectionLib` are, as you say, "methods" for `Container`, it seems reasonable that `DataLib` imports `SelectionLib`, not the other way around.

Then the user code would just import `DataLib`. This would require some refactoring. One possibility to minimize the disruption to the user code would be to rename your existing `DataLib` and `SelectionLib` to `_DataLib` and `_SelectionLib`, and have a new `DataLib` to import the necessary bits from either (or both).

As an aside, it's better to follow the PEP-8 conventions and name your modules in lowercase_with_underscores.

Comment: I did the change in the import order and no other change was needed. The code just worked! That's due to the python duck-typing: even though `SelectionLib` uses methods and attributes of the `Container` object it doesn't need to import the `Container` class.