# Namespaces comprehension

Tags: python, django, namespaces

I'm building django application and i encounter som import problems. My file structure:

```
project/
  my_app/
    models/
      __init__.py
      Article.py
      StockMovementProduct.py
    tools/
      __init__.py
      Synchronizer.py
```

**project/my_app/models/_*init*_.py**:

```
from Article import *
from StockMovementProduct import *
```

**project/my_app/models/Article.py**:

```
from django.db import models

class Article(models.Model):
[...]
```

**project/my_app/models/StockMovementProduct.py**:

```
from django.db import models
from my_app.tools import Synchronizer

class StockMovementProduct(models.Model):
  def sync_articles(self):
    sync = Synchronizer(self)
[...]
```

**project/my_app/tools/_*init*_.py** is empty

**project/my_app/tools/Synchronizer.py**:

```
from my_app.models import Article
from my_app.models import StockMovementProduct

class Synchronizer():
[...]
```

When i run my code this error is raise:

```
  File "/home/bux/Projets/project/my_app/models/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from StockMovementProduct import *
  File "/home/bux/Projets/project/my_app/models/StockMovementProduct.py", line 5, in <module>
    from my_app.tools import Synchronizer
  File "/home/bux/Projets/project/my_app/tools/Synchronizer.py", line 2, in <module>
    from my_app.models import StockMovementProduct
ImportError: cannot import name StockMovementProduct
```

I don't understand why (in Synchronizer.py) *Article* import work and *StockMovementProduct* import don't.

In Synchronizer.py i also try:

```
from my_app.models import Article
from ..models import StockMovementProduct
```

But without success. What i'm missing with import methodology ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a circular import in your code, namely your `StockMovementProduct.py` imports `Synchronizer.py` and yet `Synchronizer.py` imports `StockMovementProduct.py`.  This is a pretty common problem and there are already a lot of help on that: [Circular dependency in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/894864/circular-dependency-in-python).

Answer (score 2):

You have a circular import. StockMovementProduct imports Synchronizer, and Synchronizer imports StockMovementProduct.

You need to re structure and maybe move the common dependancies into a 3rd file. It's difficult to suggest a solution though without knowing the content