# Creating child object in parent works when classes in same file but it fails when classes in separate files

Tags: python, python-2.7, inheritance, import

Here we go:

```
class Parent(object):
    def doge(self):
        print Child().doge_name

class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Child, self).__init__()
        self.doge_name = 'Burek'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Parent().doge()
```

So cool - its gives `Burek`

But spreading this classes to different files i.e.:

```
from calls_inh.child_ppage import Child

class Parent(object):
    def doge(self):
        print Child().doge_name

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Parent().doge()
```

other file:

```
from calls_inh.parent_page import Parent


class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Child, self).__init__()
        self.doge_name = 'Burek'
```

returns:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):   File
 "D:/check/calls_inh/parent_page.py", line 1, in <module>
     from calls_inh.child_ppage import Child   File "D:\check\calls_inh\child_ppage.py", line 1, in <module>
     from calls_inh.parent_page import Parent   File "D:\check\calls_inh\parent_page.py", line 1, in <module>
     from calls_inh.child_ppage import Child ImportError: cannot import name Child

 Process finished with exit code 1
```

1. Why it pass in one case and fails in other?
2. Is there any way to make it works like in one file?

Comment: There are many problems of your code I don't know where to start, but first, it's definetly a bad idea to create an instance of subclass in parent class.

Comment: This question is more about python internals and behaviour than good practices :)

Comment: So, you're expecting to import A from B that import A, this is impossible, in any way.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python circular importing?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22187279/python-circular-importing)

Answer (score 0):

1. Answer what happens [Circular dependency in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/894864/circular-dependency-in-python)
2. Solution [How to avoid circular imports in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7336802/how-to-avoid-circular-imports-in-python)
   changing import and call in parent class make it work in separate files

   ```
   import calls_inh.child_ppage

   class Parent(object):
      def doge(self):
          print calls_inh.child_ppage.Child().doge_name
   ```