# nested import of models in django 1.7 and python 2.7

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-1.7

The title for this question may be confussing.I don't know what title should be given to this problem.

I have two models files ==> models.py in app a and models.py in app b
models.py has `class A` in app a
models.py has `class B` in app b

Both classes extend `django.db.models.Model` i.e. these classes are making database tables

I want to `import class A` from models.py from app a which imports `class B` from models.py in app b.

I want to say that both classes are using each other.

if I code like this:
models.py in app a==>

```
from b.models import B
```

models.py in app b ==>

```
from a.models import A
```

then I am getting import error that B is not defined.

how can I import both classes in both files?

Comment: Have you added app B to your **settings.py**?

Comment: yes, all other things are correct. I want to know about this one thing that how two models can interact with each other simultaneously.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create foreign key to model without importing it.  Instead of model class pass a string with app name and model name. See [the docs for ForeignKey](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey):

```
class B(models.Model):

    a = models.ForeignKey('a.A')
```

If you want to access such model somewhere in the code then import it inside a function:

```
class B(models.Model):

    def some_method(self):
        from a.models import A
        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a circular dependency question rather. You an check [Circular dependency in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/894864/circular-dependency-in-python) answer.

In short, you should either try to change your class organization to prevent this or you can use imports within functions to avoid import errors.