# Circular dependency fix in Python

Tags: python

I have a circular dependency, how can I fix this?

**LogClass**

```
... import ErrorClass

    def log(self, error):
      # isinstance(error, ErrorClass)
```

**ErrorClass**

```
... import LogClass

    log = LogClass()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Circular dependency in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/894864/circular-dependency-in-python)

Comment: Are you actually getting an error? What is it? Which module do you import in your program to trigger it?

Answer (score 0):

The ErrorClass should not be aware of the log class, hence there shouldn't be an import in it.
You can add a method to the LogClass:

```
def log_error(error):
    # isinstance(error, ErrorClass)
    log.error(...)  # if log is a python logger
```