# Share datastructures between two classes by importing

Tags: python, class, oop

I have 2 classes: Vehicle & Car.

Vehicle Class has a dictionary of Car objects & a heap.

ClassV.py:

```
from ClassC import Car
import heapq

class Vehicle:
    MapOfCars_ID = {}
    heap = [] # Stores the load factor of each car
    counter = 0

    def createCar(number, idnum):
        C = Car(number, idnum) # Create a car object
        self.MapOfCars_ID[counter] = C # Dict of Car_ID : Car Object
        self.heapq.heappush(heap, (0.0, counter)) # Heap stores load factor, Car_ID
        counter += 1

    def AssignCar():
        t = heapq.heappop(heap)
        MapOfCars_ID[t[1]].addPassenger()
```

ClassC.py is the logic for creating a Car:

```
from ClassV import Vehicle

class Car:
    size = 0;
    occupiedSeats = 0
    carId = -1
    def __init__(size, id_number):
        self.size = size
        self.carId = id_number
        print "Created Car with size " + self.size + " and ID number "+ self.carId

    def addPassenger():
        if self.occupiedSeats < self.size:
            self.occupiedSeats += 1
            # Code below adjusts the load factor of the car in the heap when a passenger is added to the car 
            # Load factor = seat-occupied/total-seats-in-the-car
            for index, value in Vehicle.heap:
                if value[1] == self.carId:
                    Vehicle.heap[index] = heap[-1]
                    heap.pop()
                    t = (float(self.occupiedSeats/self.size), self.carId)
                    heap.append(t)
                    heapq.heapify(Vehicle.heap)
                    break
        else:
            print "Car is full!"
```

The program is run from another file, main.py:

```
from ClassV import Vehicle
from random import randint

def main():
    for i in range(1, 10): # Create 10 cars
        r = randint(1,6) # Maximum number of seats could be 6 in a car
        Vehicle.createCar(r, i) # <Car size, ID>
    Vehicle.AssignCar()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The intention of this program is to create 10 cars and then assign passengers to the car having minimal occupancy.
As shall be evident from the program, The `heap` which is a class attribute of the class Vehicle is being updated in Car Class. And, Class Vehicle is creating an array of Car objects.

This gives me an error:

```
File "/home/Testing/ClassC.py", line 1, in <module>
    from ClassV import Vehicle
ImportError: cannot import name Vehicle
```

I have searched around but could really find a resolution to this problem.  What is the right way to resolve this problem?

Update: 
I got a few comments which explain that this is possibly a problem of circular imports and has 2 solution:

1. Refactor the program to avoid circular imports
2. Move the imports to the end of the module

I am looking for feedback as to how do I do either of these.

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/894864/circular-dependency-in-python)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Circular dependency in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/894864/circular-dependency-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

> Update: I got a few comments which explain that this is possibly a problem of circular imports and has 2 solution:
>
> 1. Refactor the program to avoid circular imports
> 2. Move the imports to the end of the module

Several things wrong here:

1. Your chosen nomenclature is confusing/wrong. Why is the `Vehicle` class a container for `Car` instances? I would call it something like `VehicleRegistry`, or similar, to make its intent explicit.
2. You have a fundamental design flaw, in that you are violating the responsibilities of your two classes. An instance of `Car` should be able to stand in isolation, and when I add a passenger to it, it should only affect the internal state of that instance, it should **not** affect the state of `Vehicle`, this is a recipe for fragile code, that breaks easily.
3. Do not use class level attributes, unless you know exactly what you're doing. Altering the state of a class level attributes can alter the state of said attribute for *all* instances of that class, leading to some very interesting and unexpected behaviour.

This is what I mean by a class level attributes:

```
class Person(object):
    first_name = "Bob"
    last_name = "Smith"
```

These are tied to the class, not an instance.

#### Possible solution:

Herewith some code to illustrate what I mean:

Your `addPassenger` method should only add a passenger to the car and return whether it was successful or not, nothing else.

```
def add_passenger(self) -> bool:
    if self.capacity > self.number_of_passengers:
        self.capacity = self.capacity + 1
        return True
    return False
```

You place the updating of your load factor logic in the `assign_car` method, for example:

```
def assign_car(self):
    car_id = heapq.heappop(self.heap)
    car = self.vehicle_registry[car_id]
    result = car.add_passenger()

    if result:
        # Put your load factor update logic here ...
        print("A passenger was successfully added to: {0}".format(car.id_number))
    else:
        print("A passenger could not be added to the car.")
```

**Edit[2018/09/24]:**

Alternatively, if load factor is an attribute of the `Car`, then it makes sense to place it on the instance of car itself, and allow the `VehicleRegistry` to consume the load factor state.