# Cross Call of funtions from differents python files fails

Tags: python

Sure this is a newbie and common error, but I could no find a solution because I don't know the name of this kind of issues.

I've got 2 python files p1.py and p2.py

p1.py:

```
from p2 import *

def a():
  print "Caller a --> Calling b"
  b()

def c():
  print "Caller c --> Calling d"
  d()

a()
```

p2.py:

```
from p1 import *

def b():
  print "Caller b --> Calling c"
  c()

def d():
  print "Caller d --> END"
```

When I run `p1.py` I get next error:

> NameError: global name 'b' is not defined

What I'm doing wrong? Any recommended [short] read?

Comment: this might be worth reading: https://stackabuse.com/python-circular-imports/

Comment: You have circular dependencies. Try fixing them first. https://stackabuse.com/python-circular-imports.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Circular dependency in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/894864/190597).

Comment: Unrelated, but do yourself a favor and do NOT use wild card imports (aka star imports) - they make the code brittle and hardly maintainable for no good reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, the circular imports.

Now the [short] read (example to understand your example)

p1.py:

```
from p2 import *

print "p1"
```

p2.py:

```
from p1 import *

print "p2"
```

When you run p1.py, the output is:

```
p1
p2
p1
```

What does it mean?

**p1** - the first line 'from p2 import *' imports p2, and p2 in turn launches 'from p1 import *', so p1 is determined (note: p2 is not determined yet, and this is the reason of `NameError: global name 'b' is not defined` in your example)

[import of p1 is finished]

**p2** - now lines after the import in p2

[import of p2 is finished, now return to p1]

**p1** - now lines after the import in p1

Answer (score 1):

You have a [Python Circular Imports](https://stackabuse.com/python-circular-imports/) problem.

A possible fix:

p1.py:

```
def a():
  print("Caller a --> Calling b")
  import p2
  p2.b()

def c():
  print("Caller c --> Calling d")
  import p2
  p2.d()

a()
```

py2.py

```
def b():
  print("Caller b --> Calling c")
  import p1
  p1.c()

def d():
  print ("Caller d --> END")
```

and:

```
py -m p1.py
```

OUTPUT:

> Caller a --> Calling b
>
> Caller b --> Calling c
>
> Caller a --> Calling b
>
> Caller b --> Calling c
>
> Caller c --> Calling d
>
> Caller d --> END
>
> Caller c --> Calling d
>
> Caller d --> END
>
> Process finished with exit code 0