# Problem with inherits and circular imports

Tags: python

I want to implement a class in Python that returns an instance of another class when executed.

```
from Bmodule import B
class A:
    def __new__(cls):
        return B
```

And in the module Bmodule:

```
from Amodule import A
class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        print("Class B was built")
```

But this is giving me an import error, probably due to the circular import. I know I could put both classes in a unique module, but I prefer to have them in separate ones. How can I fix it?

Thanks!!

Comment: not only the import is circular: your class definition alone is circular. this can not work...

Comment: potential duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/894864/circular-dependency-in-python

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python circular importing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22187279/python-circular-importing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
class A:
    def __new__(cls):
        from Bmodule import B
        return super().__new__(B)

class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        print("Class B was built")

print(A())
```