# Import error raised when importing file1.py in file2.py where file2.py also imports file1.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyramid

I my Python Pyramid files, File2.py is importing File1.py and File1.py is importing File2.py, which is creating an infinite loop and raising Import error.  I  need to import these to use the public varibles of the classes as well as therir functions. How do i achieve this ?

I tried below :

```
File2.py
Class File2 :

    def __init__(self, sessionId):
        from server.eventmanager.file1 import File1 # : Doesnt Work
   if __name__ == "__main__":
      from server.eventmanager.file2 import File2 # : Doesnt Work(Tried both(init+ main)/either

    def myFunc(self):
        print(File1.myvar)



File1.py        
from /server/modules/mymodule/file2 import File2

Class File1:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    myvar = False

    def updateMyVar(self,updatedvar):
        cls.myvar=updatedvar
        #Do Something

File "/server/eventmanager/file1.py", line 7, in <module>
from server.modules.mymodule.File2 import file2
File "/server/modules/mymodule/file2.py", line 13, in <module>
from server.eventmanager.File1 import file1
ImportError: cannot import name 'file1'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Circular dependency in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/894864/circular-dependency-in-python)    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/744373/circular-or-cyclic-imports-in-python

Comment: How to reolve cyclic dependency 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/744373/circular-or-cyclic-imports-in-python

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for cyclic dependency in python

[Circular dependency in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/894864/circular-dependency-in-python)[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/894864/circular-dependency-in-python)

you can have look how to resolve them.

Answer (score 0):

You can add above your first import an if clause. 
If I understood you right then you start your code with `File2.py`.

In this case you should do it like that:

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import file1
```

If you run `File2.py` `__name__` will be `__main__`. As a result the if - clause is true and you import `File1.py`. Well now `File1.py` imports `File2.py` but this time `__name__` isn't `__main__` because it doesn't run as a "main-file". This time `__name__` will be `File1` and File1 doesn't import Test2 anymore because the if clause stops it, but it still has the code of it because it already imported it one time.

Edit: 
Ok I got it! You have to put the `if __name__ == "__main__"` clause **at the top of your code** in your `File1.py`:

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    from server.eventmanager.file2  import file2  # Doesnt Work(Tried both(init+ main)/either
    from server.eventmanager.file1 import File1  # : Doesnt Work

class File2:

    def __init__(self, sessionId):
        pass

    def myFunc(self):
        print(File1.myvar)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried above(updated snippet in original posted question), but i'm getting error from Pylint, telling File1 is unresolved reference. Isn't init same as main ?

Comment: can you edit your post and add your code which you have at this moment pls?

Comment: Updated the post.Please check