# how can i fix circular import error in two separate files?

Tags: python, function, import, circular-dependency

i have two python files named a.py and b.py

a's content :

```
from b import test
global name
name = "jack"
test()
```

b's content :

```
from a import name
def test():
    return name
```

I get this error when i run it :

```
most likely due to a circular import
```

how can i fix this? (i need test function to be in b.py)

full error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/armin/w/python/a.py", line 1, in <module>
from b import test
File "/home/armin/w/python/b.py", line 1, in <module>
from a import name
File "/home/armin/w/python/a.py", line 1, in <module>
from b import test
ImportError: cannot import name 'test' from partially initialized 
module 'b' (most likely due to a circular import) 
(/home/armin/w/python/b.py)
```

Comment: I would fix this by making `test` accept the value as a parameter, and having `a` pass it in, rather than expecting `b` to grab it. That is, after all, the normal and expected way to communicate with functions: you should prefer to pass arguments to parameters to get information in, and use the return value to get information out, rather than using globals. That said, you might also try the suggestions in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/894864/circular-dependency-in-python.

Comment: But at any rate, please show [complete](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146/why-should-i-post-complete-errors-why-isnt-the-message-itself-enough) errors. This isn't even the entire description of the problem, let alone a stack trace.

Comment: i added full error

Answer (score 0):

What you can try is to define `name` in a separated file:

a's content :

```py
from b import test
from c import name # Only if you really need name here.

test()
```

b's content :

```py
from c import name

def test():
    return name
```

c's content:

```py
global name
name = "jack"
```