# How to structure python project to allow mutual dependency?

Tags: python, import, package, circular-dependency, modulenotfounderror

### How to import both car and abstract_vehicle in main.py?

I keep getting circular dependencies error or ModuleNotFoundError.

#### Project structure

```
├── vehicles
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── abstract_vehicle.py
│   └── car.py
│   └── motor.py
└── main.py
```

#### car.py

```
from abstract_vehicle import abstract_vehicle
class car(abstract_vehicle):
    #do sth
```

#### **init**.py

```
import abstract_vehicle
import car
```

#### main.py

```
from vehicles import car, abstract_vehicle #error

vehicle_a = car()
def do_sth(a:abstract_vehicle):
    pass

do_sth(vehicle_a)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Circular dependency in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/894864/circular-dependency-in-python)

Comment: Notwithstanding the advice in the question linked to by @Woodford circular dependencies that cause import errors almost always indicate a design problem. In my three decades of writing Python I only worked on one project where this was a problem. We "solved" the immediate problem by using a hard to understand lazy import; i.e., a bandaid. We fixed it properly as soon as we could devote some resources to restructure the code.