# How to import the class within the same directory or sub directory?

Tags: python, python-import

I have a directory that stores all the **.py** files.

```
bin/
   main.py
   user.py # where class User resides
   dir.py # where class Dir resides
```

I want to use classes from **user.py** and **dir.py** in **main.py**.
How can I import these Python classes into **main.py**?
Furthermore, how can I import class `User` if **user.py** is in a sub directory?

```
bin/
    dir.py
    main.py
    usr/
        user.py
```

Comment: See also answers in [Python: import a file from a subdirectory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1260792/python-import-a-file-from-a-subdirectory).

Comment: [I answered similar question here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39152647/1911412)

Answer (score 1243, accepted):

## Python 2

Make an empty file called `__init__.py` in the same directory as the files. That will signify to Python that it's "ok to import from this directory".

Then just do...

```
from user import User
from dir import Dir
```

The same holds true if the files are in a subdirectory - put an `__init__.py` in the subdirectory as well, and then use regular import statements, with dot notation. For each level of directory, you need to add to the import path.

```
bin/
    main.py
    classes/
        user.py
        dir.py
```

So if the directory was named "classes", then you'd do this:

```
from classes.user import User
from classes.dir import Dir
```

## Python 3

Same as previous, but prefix the module name with a `.` if not using a subdirectory:

```
from .user import User
from .dir import Dir
```

Comment: Is it required that the `__init__.py` is empty. I would like to import all submodules in package `__init__.py` i.e add lines: `from Module1 impotr *` for all modules (files) I have in directory. Is it possible?

Comment: If `__init__.py` is *not* empty, then whatever is in `__init__.py` is what will be available when you import the package (and things not imported into `__init__.py` won't be available at all).

Comment: Why is an `__init__.py` file needed at all? If I put all three files in the same directory and run `main.py`, it's able to `import` from the other two modules fine without it. What am I missing?

Comment: Because that's how Python identifies directories from which you're allowed to import. The directory of the script you're running is an exception - you're always allowed to import from it.

Comment: Sorry Amber, I put an empty `__init__.py` file in the 2 subdirectories I have (gui/ and logic/), but I am still having import problems `ImportError: No module named 'player'`
, this `player.py` is inside `logic/`, and there's the `__init__.py`, as I told you. What could be the problem?

Comment: @nbro & Amber: FWIW, I think something subtle has changed with regards to `__init__.py` and being able to import other modules in the same directory. Specifically `import`s of other modules in the same directory as the `__init__.py` file itself which worked in Python 2.7.8, failed in Python 3.4.1. To fix it I had to prefix each of them with the subdirectory's name and a dot (i.e. `import module` had to be changed to `import subdirectory.module`). Fortunately it still worked in Python 2.7.8 after doing this.

Comment: @martineau Exactly, and it's a more object-oriented way of importing modules.

Comment: @nbo: Since the other modules are in the same directory as the `__init__.py` and that it used to work without the prefix, I consider it a bug...perhaps an unintended consequence of something else that was changed between Python 2.x to 3.x with regards to module and package importation.

Comment: I can confirm this solution is no longer functional. You might wish to correct, amend or outright delete it.

Comment: I likewise don't see this working in Python 3 anymore. I think this is because my module only contain functions, no classes.

Comment: Ah, yes I solved it. Use: from . import fileloader if your module has no classes

Comment: What do you have to do it you have stuff in your __init__.py file?  I try importing from the same folder like here, and It can't find it. If I import those two files on the __init__.py it works... but doesn't if you try to import from any other

Comment: @darkgaze if an `__init__.py` file is non-empty, than the module will only contain what is defined in the `__init__.py` file. So your `__init__.py` needs to import from the local directory anything you want other files to be able to import from the module. (An empty `__init__.py` means to just reference the rest of the directory implicitly.)

Comment: @Amber Ok. But HOW do I do it. doing imports? How should those imports be?  import childName?  or import thisName.childName?. And how do you import the submodules from each of them? import childName too?

Comment: By the way, I found: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/#id8  PEP 328 talks specifically about the relative imports.

Comment: The first few lines of this answer were bad and didn't work at all. On the point working answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41276151/129202

Comment: With Python 3.8 the import will be `import path.to.file.containing.Class` and add `__init__.py` in the directory containing the final .py file. However what is the solution if the path starts in an ancestor of the directory containing the file with the `import`. We cannot specify the path like `../../end.of.the.path.file.containg.Class`. This can happen if there are multiple directories in the project directory, of which one contains the Class to import. What is the solution, if any.

Comment: python 3.9.2 no "."  required. eg "from dog import Dog" where class Dog resides in dog.py

Comment: Maybe it's time to move the Python 3 stuff to the top?

Comment: doesn't work, throw out "attempted relative import with no known parent package"

Answer (score 183):

I just learned (thanks to [martineau's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4142151/python-how-to-import-the-class-within-the-same-directory-or-sub-directory#comment42933868_4142178)) that, in order to import classes from files within the same directory, you would now write in Python 3:

```
from .user import User
from .dir import Dir
```

Comment: if i try this no i get the following error `ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package` but error goes away when i change to `from user import User
`

Comment: I use from .fileloader import Fileloader and get ImportError: cannot import name 'Fileloader'

Comment: @Korpel: Following the discussions in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11536764/how-to-fix-attempted-relative-import-in-non-package-even-with-init-py i come to realize that wether the above given import works or not depends on: 
[1] how your script is called (as package or not) 
[2] where the actual work path is when you execute it 
[3] how the path variable of your run environment is populated

Comment: @Korpel: I noticed that the . before the module name is required only when a __init__.py file is present, if not the . can/must be omitted.

Comment: Why is it so difficult to find a clear answer for this question? All I want to do is create a class in a seperate file and then import that class into a different file which is in the same directory. If I use a relative import like this answer I also get the VlaueError

Comment: Anyone have a solution to this yet? @Jiren did you find one? Seems like such a simple problem as you say...

Comment: @Korpel I got `ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package`, not sure if it's the same error, but I used `from user.User import User`, it worked.

Comment: @Jiren try `from user.User import User`, no `.`

Comment: After 100 years of innovation, finally we cannot even do "Hello world". Is this joke the single source of truth? No matter how hard we try, we cannot share code in the same directory. How can it be worse, even if somebody tried to sabotage a project?

Answer (score 77):

From python3.3 upwards, `__init__.py` is [no longer necessary](http://python-notes.curiousefficiency.org/en/latest/python_concepts/import_traps.html). If the current directory of the console is the directory where the python script is located, everything works fine with

```
import user
```

However, this won't work if called from a different directory, which does not contain `user.py`.
In that case, use

```
from . import user
```

This works even if you want to import the whole file instead of just a class from there.

Comment: I'm using pylint in vs code, and was having trouble with a same-directory import always being flagged as an error (`import user` was underlined in red); changed to the relative import (`from . import user`) and the linter no longer flagged it.

Comment: how to do you fin the current directory

Comment: @xiaodai not sure what you mean. Does my second snippet not work for you? To answer your question itself, probably with `os.getcwd()`  but that shouldn't be necessary

Comment: " from dog import Dog"  works for me 3.9.2

Comment: As of python3.3 to be more precise. Thanks @lucidbrot, interesting contribution!

Comment: Perfect. Been going 'round in circles for 24 hours. Python needs to be reversioned, because wading through out of date suggestions is becoming a nightmare.

Answer (score 54):

In your `main.py`:

```
from user import Class
```

where `Class` is the name of the class you want to import.

If you want to call a method of `Class`, you can call it using:

`Class.method`

Note that there should be an empty `__init__.py` file in the same directory.

Comment: What do you do if the module you're trying to import has no classes? Just raw functions? In python 2 all I had to do was 'import module'. Doesn't work in python 3, neither does 'import .module'

Comment: This works in python3 after deleted the `__init__.py`.

Answer (score 20):

If user.py and dir.py are not including classes then

```py
from .user import User
from .dir import Dir
```

is not working. You should then import as

```py
from . import user
from . import dir
```

Comment: could you clarify on what you mean by 'not including classes'?

Comment: I mean that in the `file.py` there are defined only variables and functions `def` and no classes as described [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html)

Answer (score 15):

You can import the module and have access through its name if you don't want to mix functions and classes with yours

```
import util # imports util.py

util.clean()
util.setup(4)
```

or you can import the functions and classes to your code

```
from util import clean, setup
clean()
setup(4)
```

you can use wildchar * to import everything in that module to your code

```
from util import *
clean()
setup(4)
```

Comment: import * is not recommended anymore

Answer (score 11):

To make it more simple to understand:

Step 1: lets go to one directory, where all will be included

```
$ cd /var/tmp
```

Step 2: now lets make a class1.py file which has a class name Class1 with some code

```
$ cat > class1.py <<\EOF
class Class1:
    OKBLUE = '\033[94m'
    ENDC = '\033[0m'
    OK = OKBLUE + "[Class1 OK]: " + ENDC
EOF
```

Step 3: now lets make a class2.py file which has a class name Class2 with some code

```
$ cat > class2.py <<\EOF
class Class2:
    OKBLUE = '\033[94m'
    ENDC = '\033[0m'
    OK = OKBLUE + "[Class2 OK]: " + ENDC
EOF
```

Step 4: now lets make one main.py which will be execute once to use Class1 and Class2 from 2 different files

```
$ cat > main.py <<\EOF
"""this is how we are actually calling class1.py and  from that file loading Class1"""
from class1 import Class1 
"""this is how we are actually calling class2.py and  from that file loading Class2"""
from class2 import Class2

print Class1.OK
print Class2.OK
EOF
```

Step 5: Run the program

```
$ python main.py
```

The output would be

```
[Class1 OK]: 
[Class2 OK]:
```

Comment: And what happens if this doesn't work and main.py can't read class1 or class2?... what are we missing?

Answer (score 11):

For Python 3+, suppose you have this structure:

```
A/
  __init__.py
  bar.py
  foo.py
```

In your `__init__.py` file, you can put **`from . import foo`**

then you can import foo in bar file

```
# A/bar.py
from foo import YourClass
```

The purpose of the `__init__.py` files is to include optional initialization code that runs as different levels of a package are encountered. everything you put in the `__init__.py` will be initialized during the package load.

Comment: This was the only solution that worked for me

Answer (score 10):

**Python 3**

---

Same `directory`.

import file:`log.py`

import class: `SampleApp()`.

```
import log
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = log.SampleApp()
    app.mainloop()
```

or

directory is `basic`.

import in file: `log.py`.

import class: `SampleApp()`.

```
from basic import log
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = log.SampleApp()
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: the most easiest to understand answer

Answer (score 7):

```
from user import User 
from dir import Dir
```

Comment: This worked for me without having __init__.py file for both Python 2.7 and Python 3.6.

Comment: @imsrgadich it works as long as you're running python in the directory containing the files. This is an exception. See [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4142151/how-to-import-the-class-within-the-same-directory-or-sub-directory#comment27915014_4142178)

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure why this work but using Pycharm build `from file_in_same_dir import class_name`

The IDE complained about it but it seems it still worked. I'm using Python 3.7

Comment: Use absolute path.
`from bin.user import User`
assuming **bin** is the root directory.  Also this works for both python 2 and python 3.

Answer (score 2):

For python3

import from sibling: `from .user import User`
import from nephew: `from .usr.user import User`

Comment: This works. `from file import MyClass` doesn't work if package is installed via `pipx`, but does work when installed with pip. `from .file import MyClass` however is OK.

Answer (score 1):

If you have `filename.py` in the same folder, you can easily import it like this:

```py
import filename
```

I am using python3.7

Answer (score 1):

I cannot submit an edit for the top answer, so based on some pointers given in comments above, another thing to try out is:

```py
from subfolder.MyClassFile import MyClass
```

And that's it. Just *remember* to have an `__init__.py` empty file in our `subfolder`.

Just for reference, the solution works if your structure is something like this:

```
your_project/
    __ini__.py
    main.py
    subfolder/
        __init__.py
        MyClassFile.py  <-- You want this
```

`MyClassFile.py` contains the class `MyClass`.

Answer (score 0):

**Python3**

use

```
from .user import User inside dir.py file
```

and

```
use from class.dir import Dir inside main.py
or from class.usr import User inside main.py
```

like so

Comment: This answer doesn't really add anything more than the other answer already do, and has no explanation. Is there some way you could [edit your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/59201996/edit) to add to or improve it? Because otherwise, it stands to be downvoted [like this answer was](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57635519/11384392) or removed entirely.

Answer (score 0):

```
# My Python version: 3.7
# IDE: Pycharm 2021.1.2 Community

# Have "myLib" in folder "labs":

class Points:
    def __init__(self, x = 0, y = 0):
        self.__x = x
        self.__y = y
    def __str__(self):
        return f"x = {self.__x}, y = {self.__y}"

# Have "myFile" in (same) folder "labs":

from myFile import Point

p1 = Point(1, 4)
p2 = Point(1, 4)
print(f"p1: {p1}, p2: {p2}")

# Result:
# p1: x = 1, y = 4, p2: x = 1, y = 4

# Good Luck!
```

Comment: Code-only answers are not particularly helpful. Please add some descriptions of how this code solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed Python does not provide an elegant solution for this everyday use-case. It is especially problematic when you are testing your code that eventually will be delivered as part of a Python package. Here is an approach that has worked for me:

dir
|

- file1.py
- file2.py

And let's say you want to import file2 from file1.

```
# In file1.py:
try:
     # This works when packaged as Python package
     from . import file2
except:
     # This works when simply invoking file1 as a module (i.e. python file1)
     import file2

# rest of the code ...
```

Answer (score 0):

In a sufficiently complicated project, we can't do hello world with python imports. When all else fails I had some success with the following

```
sys.path.append(os.path.join(pathlib.Path(__file__).parent.resolve()))
```

Answer (score -2):

Just too brief,
Create a file `__init__.py` is classes directory and then import it to your script like following (Import all case)

```
from classes.myscript import *
```

Import selected classes only

```
from classes.myscript import User
from classes.myscript import Dir
```

Comment: Wildcard imports as seen in this answer are generally considered bad style as described in [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/?#id23).

Answer (score -3):

to import from the same directory

```
from . import the_file_you_want_to_import
```

to import from sub directory the directory should contain

> **init**.py

file other than you files then

from directory import your_file

Comment: I don't think this answer adds anything that other answers did not, and also is not a comprehensive summary of the other answers. So I wonder why you wrote it