# Importing variables from another file?

Tags: python, file, variables, import

How can I import variables from one file to another?

example: `file1` has the variables `x1` and `x2` how to pass them to `file2`?

How can I import **all** of the variables from one to another?

Comment: *Why* do you want to do that? Depending on the use-case, this is actually not what you really want.

Answer (score 236, accepted):

```
from file1 import *
```

will import all objects and methods in file1

Comment: Do note, however, this is generally something you [should not do](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/doanddont.html#from-module-import).

Comment: As David notes, this pollutes the namespace and can have catastrophic consequences by masking objects and functions from other modules including those in the standard distro

Comment: I tried to do it, but it seems like python can't find the *file1*, because I'm getting this error: `ImportError: No module named file1`

Comment: Did you have a `__init__.py` file? See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4142151/python-how-to-import-the-class-within-the-same-directory-or-sub-directory) for more details.

Comment: Prepending a . at the beginning of file1 worked for me. i.e
```from .file1 import *```

Comment: how to map this to a variable name
e.g from file1 import *  f1

Answer (score 129):

Import `file1` inside `file2`:

To import all variables from file1 without flooding file2's namespace, use:

```
import file1

#now use file1.x1, file2.x2, ... to access those variables
```

To import all variables from file1 to file2's namespace( not recommended):

```
from file1 import *
#now use x1, x2..
```

From the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/doanddont.html#at-module-level):

> While it is valid to use `from module import *` at module level it is
>   usually a bad idea. For one, this loses an important property Python
>   otherwise has — you can know where each toplevel name is defined by a
>   simple “search” function in your favourite editor. You also open
>   yourself to trouble in the future, if some module grows additional
>   functions or classes.

Comment: and if I have 1000 variables to pass?

Comment: @Ofek Just use `import file1`  then.

Comment: It doesn't import the variables :\

Comment: it does import the variables, though you'll have to prepend `file1.varX` for each file.

Answer (score 77):

Best to import **x1** and **x2** explicitly:

```
from file1 import x1, x2
```

This allows you to avoid unnecessary namespace conflicts with variables and functions from `file1` while working in `file2`.

But if you really want, you can import **all** the variables:

```
from file1 import *
```

Answer (score 33):

Actually this is not really the same to import a variable with:

```
from file1 import x1
print(x1)
```

and

```
import file1
print(file1.x1)
```

Altough at import time x1 and file1.x1 have the same value, they are not the same variables. For instance, call a function in file1 that modifies x1 and then try to print the variable from the main file: you will not see the modified value.

Comment: This is a major surprise to me!  Thank you for this answer - and now I have to find out how to do this _properly_.

Answer (score 17):

first.py:

```
a=5
```

second.py:

```
import first
print(first.a)
```

The result will be 5.

Answer (score 13):

**script1.py**

```
title="Hello world"
```

**script2.py** is where we using script1 variable

**Method 1:**

```
import script1
print(script1.title)
```

**Method 2:**

```
from script1 import title
print(title)
```

Answer (score 10):

Marc [response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50253384/8053370) is correct. Actually, you can print the memory address for the variables `print(hex(id(libvar))` and you can see the addresses are different.

```
# mylib.py
libvar = None
def lib_method():
    global libvar
    print(hex(id(libvar)))

# myapp.py
from mylib import libvar, lib_method
import mylib

lib_method()
print(hex(id(libvar)))
print(hex(id(mylib.libvar)))
```

Answer (score 0):

if you need to import of a variable from a dir on the same level or below you can use "import_module" coming from you cwd of the project:

```
        from importlib import import_module
        mod = import_module(
            f"{cwd}.source.myfolder.myfile"
        )
        var = getattr(mod, "my_variable")
```