# Using import our script with Python

Tags: python

I don't know how explain what I want do so I think with code example you can understand.

y.py

```
y = 0

import printy
```

printy.py

```
import y

print y

NameError: name 'y' is not defined
```

When I call scripts with import works perfect but I want to know how I can share variables.

y.py

```
import printy
```

printy.py

```
y = 0

print y

result = 0
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Importing variables from another file (python)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17255737/importing-variables-from-another-file-python)

Comment: try: `import printy; print printy.y` or `from printy import y; print y`.

Comment: It's generally **not** a good idea to have two modules that import each other, so try to avoid that if you can. Do a search for "circular imports" for more info.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know which is which file, (assuming each code block is a different file) it should work, and share `variables` if `import`ing them works. Also, I would write it like this:

file y.py:

```
from printy import *

y = 0
```

file printy.py:

```
from y import *

print y
```

Also, both files have to already exist at time of running, and they have to saved into the same folder.

EDIT: If `result = 0` is the output, then everything is working fine. Also, if this doesn't work, I'd do `printy.print(y)`

Comment: Also, if you want to do more complex code, it will work best to save the code, in file being retrieved, in a `function`.