# hiding variable or limit lenght of it in python - without manipulating it's value

Tags: string, python-3.x

I have a variable x, which has a string of 500 and more charhacters.

The problem is, it is very annoying when you do coding and this long string takes half of the screen.

My question is: is it possible to hide the value of variable, with out manipulating it's value? Open for any solution to solve problem. Thank you.

Comment: Do you mean in your code editing program? You could store the string in a different file and import it if you really want to but this seems like a specific task for an IDE.

Comment: yes, in my code editing program. i've been thinking about this idea, was just wondering if there is anything more pythonic about it:)

Comment: I don't think having crazy long strings hard coded into your program is very pythonesque to begin with, are they for pretty output of a terminal application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its a little backwards of a solution but you can call X in a separate program and import it to your main program.

[Importing variables from another file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17255737/importing-variables-from-another-file-python)

Here is a link to how to do that. 
Another solution would be to call it at the top of your program and just type everything below it.