# How do I get a variable from one file into another file

Tags: python, file, variables, pygame, self

I want to get my class variables from file x and use them in file y. How can I go about doing this?

I have seen that you would use from fileName import * but when i use this i get a error "import * only allowed at one module level"

Comment: You can find the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17255737/importing-variables-from-another-file-python

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
StackOverflow is not a coding or tutorial service.

Answer (score 1):

### A.py

```
VAR1 = 'foo'
VAR2 = 'bar
```

### B.py

```
from A import VAR1, VAR2
```

Assuming files A.py and B.py are located in the same folder...

Comment: I do this but i comes up with import * only allowed at one module

Comment: import * [AKA wild import] should give you the same effect

Comment: what do you mean by wil import

Comment: it's just a term , saying you're importing the entire global variables from the module. 
So in this specific example:
from A import VAR1, VAR2
and
from A import *
will have the same effect, which is importing VAR1, VAR2 from A.py to B.py

Comment: but still when i do that I get the same message