# How to access a variable from another file?

Tags: python, variables, tkinter, import, module

I am creating a login form in which the user enters their customer ID and forename to login. I need to use the customer ID that is entered in this form in another file. Here is my code for the first file (the login form)

```
def customer_login():
    global CustomerID, Forename
    master = Tk()
    Label(master, text="Customer Login", fg='black', bg='turquoise', font=('comicsans', 14)).grid(row=0)
    Label(master, text="Please enter your Customer ID", fg='black', bg='turquoise', font=('comicsans', 12)).grid(row=1)
    Label(master, text="Please enter your forename", fg='black', bg='turquoise', font=('comicsans', 12)).grid(row=2)

    CustomerID = Entry(master)
    Forename = Entry(master)

    CustomerID.grid(row=1, column=1)
    Forename.grid(row=2, column=1)
    CustomerIDSave=CustomerID.get()
```

I then need to use the `CustomerIDSave` variable in another. I tried to import the file as a module but this didn't work. Any ideas on what I could do? I can't have the program all in one large file, as it would be far too big.

Comment: Indent your code properly

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Importing variables from another file (python)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17255737/importing-variables-from-another-file-python)

Comment: in this function you should use `return CustomerIDSave` and `result = custom_login()`. And after you import another file you should use `another_file.another_function(result)`

Comment: okay thanks! I will try that, but what do you mean by the last bit?

Answer (score 0):

`from yourfilename import *`, and this will import all methods and objects.

Comment: PEP8 discourages wildcard imports.

Comment: Wildcard imports work, but are not good code practice. It's too hard for people reading your code to understand where a particular imported variable comes from. You should always make your imports explicit when possible.