# Calling one script from another and importing its values

Tags: python

I have two scripts `main.py` and `get_number.py`. The script `get_number.py` returns a random number whenver it's called. I want to call this script from `main.py` and print all these returned values. In other words, the script `get_number.py` is the following:

```
def get_random():
    return np.random.uniform(0,1)
```

Now I have the following code in `main.py`

```
import get_number

n_call = 4

values = np.zeros(n_call)

for i in range(n_call):
      values[i]= get_number.get_random()

print(values)
```

However I am receiving the error that `No module named get_number`. How would I go about accomplishing this task?

Comment: Try a relative import. `import .get_number`. Oops, incorrect syntax. schwo fixed this, check theirs.

Comment: @BrandonIbbotson: It shows `invalid syntax`

Comment: `from . import get_number`

Comment: @schwobaseggl: `Parent module not loaded, cannot perform relative import `

Comment: Add an empty `__init__.py` to the folder where your two scripts reside!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you can import just as importing another libraries

```
from file1 import *
```

> [Importing variables from another file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17255737/7447240)

I Found some similar Problems up here

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing between `get_number` and `get_random`

**main.py:**

```
import numpy as np
from get_number import get_random

n_call = 4

values = np.zeros(n_call)

for i in range(n_call):
      values[i]= get_random()

print(values)
```

`Out: [ 0.63433276  0.36541908  0.83485925  0.59532567]`

**get_number:**

```
import numpy as np

def get_random():
    return np.random.uniform(0,1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to import this way:
In `main.py`

```
from get_number import get_random
n_call = 4

values = np.zeros(n_call)

for i in range(n_call):
      values[i]= get_random()

print(values)
```