# How to import file with variables?

Tags: python, python-2.7, import

In Python (2.7), I'd like to create several variables in a file. Then use those variables in other files. There aren't any classes or function. Just accessing those variables from different files.

How is that done for the file containing variables, which might look like this?

variables.py

```
a = 1
b = 2
c = 3
```

Then in a file that wants to use those variables?

file1.py

```
print a + b
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Another way is to import file than use filename to access variables:

```
import variables

print variables.a + variables.b
```

Comment: This is a better implementation - it keeps the naming clear.

Comment: This technique seems to handle the pylint error I commented on from the first answer.

Comment: It's better to use this import while your file only contains variables.

Comment: Definitely better.  Answered my way since exactly asked what he needed. :)

Answer (score 4):

If those are in proper python format i.e. the way you have mentioned above

In your file1.py 
You can just do this.

```
from variables import *

print a + b
```

Comment: Why does pylint keep complaining "E0602:Undefined variable 'myvar1'"?

Comment: What's your filename for keeping your variables?

Comment: Same as in the OP: variables.py.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `import` to import your work from that file to the next, like so:

```
from variables import *

print a + b
```

If you're still confused, refer to this post here which will give you an in-depth explanation: [Python: How to import other Python files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2349991/python-how-to-import-other-python-files)

Comment: pylint complains when this technique is used.

Answer (score 0):

It is exactly as people told above

[Importing variables from another file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17255737/importing-variables-from-another-file/17255749#17255749)

Here it will have more information about how to do it with methods and scripts. This also aplies to your problem