# What is the Best Method for Importing, Reading and Adding to a List Saved in a Text File?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

How would I call upon a list in an external .txt file in Python and be able to use it in my code and add to it?

Comment: *external `list`* meaning? `list` defined in another Python file?

Comment: This would require a lot more information, starting with the format that the list is currently in. As it stands, the question is too broad to give any useful suggestions. Please see [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for an outline on the kind of information to include in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't clear what you mean when you say external list, so I'm going to assume that you mean data stored in a text file.
To read from a file, use Python's file methods. If you want to read the entire contents of the file, use the read method of the file object.

```
f = open("mylist.txt", "r")
contents = f.read()
f.close()
```

With a list, however, it may be useful to read the file one line at a time. In this case, you can either use the readline method

```
f = open("mylist.txt", "r")
line1 = f.readline()
line2 = f.readline()
f.close()
```

or loop over the file object

```
f = open("mylist.txt", "r")
for line in f:
    #do something with line
f.close()
```

To modify the file, open the file in write or append mode and write to it.

```
f = open("mylist.txt", "w") #Overwrites any data in the file
f.write("foo\n")
f.write("bar\n")
f.close()

f = open("mylist.txt", "a") #Preserves and adds to data in the file
f.write("foo\n")
f.write("bar\n")
f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this. Here is one very simple way (for pure demo purposes):

(within the same directory, create two files)

File 1: `mydata.py` - this store the "external list"

```
dummy = [1, 2, 3]
```

File 2: `main_program.py` - this import the "external list" and print it

```
from mydata import dummy
print(dummy)
# print out [1, 2, 3]
```

Then just run the python code like this:

```
python main_program.py
```

Reference: [Importing variables from another file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17255737/importing-variables-from-another-file)