# How to get variables from another Python 3 script？

Tags: python-3.x

I have a.py which the code is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#coding=utf-8
def aaa(p):
    m=1
    n=2
    z=m+n+p
    return z
```

Now i want to get "m" and "n" from a.py in another python script,
how should I do？

Answer (score 0):

use `import a`
and then you can use `a.m` and `a.n`

If you dont want to use `a.m` the you should import like `from a import m` and then use them as they are(`m` and `n`). But this way isn't the recommended way, as it would confuse you in identifying which variable is from which file.

I just found a similar question. Have a look.

[Importing variables from another file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17255737/importing-variables-from-another-file)

Comment: HI,TeraBaapBC.I tried to use "import a",but i "print (a.m)", that feedback "AttributeError: module 'a' has no attribute 'm'"....

Comment: did you execute a.py?

Comment: Save both files in same directory and the execute both files. It will work

Comment: i saved two files in the same directory ,and my b.py is
`import a

print (a.m)` ,but when i run  `python b.py` ,that feedback "AttributeError: module 'a' has no attribute 'm'" ,where am i wrong?