# How do I get variables from a different file in a different directory into a python file

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I am trying to get a ton of variables from a file in a different directory WITHOUT just copying and pasting, as thats just cheap, and makes one need to edit ALL the files that use that set of variables.

`D:/Tiller OS/garden/memId.py`:

```
mem11 = "D:/Tiller OS/memory/mem1/mem1-1.mem"
mem12 = "D:/Tiller OS/memory/mem1/mem1-2.mem"
mem13 = "D:/Tiller OS/memory/mem1/mem1-3.mem"
mem21 = "D:/Tiller OS/memory/mem2/mem2-1.mem"
mem22 = "D:/Tiller OS/memory/mem2/mem2-2.mem"
mem23 = "D:/Tiller OS/memory/mem2/mem2-3.mem"
mem31 = "D:/Tiller OS/memory/mem3/mem3-1.mem"
mem32 = "D:/Tiller OS/memory/mem3/mem3-2.mem"
mem33 = "D:/Tiller OS/memory/mem3/mem3-3.mem"
memro1 = "D:/Tiller OS/memory/romem/memro-1.mem"
memro2 = "D:/Tiller OS/memory/romem/memro-2.mem"
memro3 = "D:/Tiller OS/memory/romem/memro-3.mem"
```

How do I get all this info into a file at `D:/Tiller OS/programs/prog.py`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Importing variables from another file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17255737/importing-variables-from-another-file)

Comment: Wouldn't that be better handled by some sort of config file?

Comment: @melpomene How would I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `D:/Tiller OS/garden/` is on your path, you can just do `from memId import mem11`, etc. It doesn't matter whether something is a function, class, or other object when importing in Python.

However, if all that `memId.py` contains is a list of these variables, I agree with @melpomene that you it might be better to use a different format to store these. You could use, for example, a [TOML](https://github.com/toml-lang/toml) file. The format you have above is already valid TOML, so you'd just rename it to `memId.toml` and then in `prog.py` you could do something like

```py
import toml
mem_path = "D:/Tiller OS/garden/memId.toml"
mems = toml.load(mem_path)
```

`mems` would then be a dictionary and you could access `mem11` as `mems["mem11"]` and similarly for the others. `toml` is not in the standard library, so you would need to `pip install toml` if you don't have it. You could just use a JSON file instead if you don't want that; `json` is in the standard library. However, I think TOML is nicer than JSON, and JSON would require changing the format of your file.

Comment: I accidentally posted my answer before it was complete - see the last paragraph above. You need to `pip install toml`.