# How to import list from main.py to task.py with Python 3 PyCharm?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, import, pycharm

How can I use a list from main.py, in the task.py? Code below.

main.py:

```
import task.py
list_list = ["test1","test2"]
task.print_func()
```

task.py:

```
from main import list_list
def print_func():
     for x in list_list:
          print(x)
```

In this way I got the following error:

AttributeError: module 'task' has no attribute 'print_func'

Comment: And I don't want to pass here: task.print_func(list_list)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Importing variables from another file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17255737/importing-variables-from-another-file)

Comment: Sorry, but that's doesn't work for me. I read it before.

Answer (score 2):

You are creating a circular dependency (see e.g. [this explanation](https://stackabuse.com/python-circular-imports/)), which is something you generally want to avoid.

The program flow would roughly be as follows:

- You call `python main.py`
- `import task` is executed, to load `print_func` from `task.py`
- `task.py` is executed, going straight back to `main.py` to retrieve `list_list`
  ...

To fix your problem, you could do the following:

main.py:

```
import task
list_list = ["test1","test2"]

# Only run this, if main.py is run directly, not in import
if __name__ == "__main__":
    task.print_func()
```

task.py: (no changes)

```
from main import list_list
def print_func():
     for x in list_list:
          print(x)
```

This change allows `task.py` to import `list_list` without trying to execute `task.print_func` which cannot be defined at that point (as its definition depends on `list_list`).

Some general points:

1. I don't see why you want to import `list_list` from main for use in `task.print_func` - passing the list as argument would be better in my opinion.
2. Execute as little code as possible on indent level 0 in a python file you want to import somewhere else. Read e.g. here: [What does if __name__ == "__main__": do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do) for some details.

All things considered, I would do it as follows:

main.py

```
import task

if __name__ == "__main__":
    list_list = ["test1","test2"]
    task.print_func(list_list)
```

task.py:

```
def print_func(list_list):
     for x in list_list:
          print(x)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use below code.

### main.py

```
import task
list_list = ["test1","test2"]

if __name__=="__main__":
    task.print_func()
```

### task.py

```
from main import list_list

def print_func():
     for x in list_list:
          print(x)
```