# Importing variables in Python, new topic as the old one does not work for me

Tags: python, file, variables, import

I have read all of the answers of the following link : [Importing variables from another file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17255737/importing-variables-from-another-file)
I have tried what they say, to import my variables from one file to another by tapping :

`from file1 import *`

or

`from file1 import var1`

Unfortunately it does not work as intented because I am not importing the variable only but the whole file1. That is not the purpose (I really only want var1, the script is rather big) so I am wondering if I am the only one noticing this behaviour as everybody there looks satisfied with the answer.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: `from file1 import var1` is better code, but any approach you use will _always_ import the whole module so there are no savings to be made

Comment: Python is interpreted and it has no way of finding out where `var1` is in the file, which is why it has to run the entire code and then import `var1`.

Comment: @roganjosh Is correct. See [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/187403/import-module-vs-from-module-import-function) for a better explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You most likely have some code running in your file which is either outside of defined functions all together or in a main function that is run automaticalls upon running (and thus also when imported.

In other words if file1 looks like this:

```
var1 = 'hello'

def printHello():
    print var1
```

then writing `from file1 import var1` will only import that. If on the other hand file1 looks like this:

```
var1 = 'hello'

print var1
```

It will import `var1` but also print 'hello'.