# How to import a variable from the main file in Python Processing?

Tags: python, processing

Is there any way to import a variable from the main file to another class.

For instance:

```py
# main tab

x = 10
y = 20

def setup():
    size(400,400)

def draw():
    background(0)
```

```py
# Ball.py 

class Ball:

def myMethod(self):
# here I want to import the 'x or y' variables from the main file.
```

In Java Processing variables declared in the main tab can be used from everywhere, but when it comes to Python Processing that's not the case.

Comment: A variable cannot be _"called"_.

Comment: You can import the variables Source:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17255737/importing-variables-from-another-file

Comment: ye something like from .main import x

Comment: btw these are files not tabs

Comment: In processing they are tabs so I can see why he was confused. In the java version it is compiled as it was one big file.

Answer (score 3):

**Transferring Data Between Files**

You can transfer data between files, if that is what you are trying to do. You would be essentially creating your own modules.

```
from main import x, y
```

Something  along these lines

**Using Data from Outside a Class Inside the Class**

I think you are just wanting to use the x and y variables inside of the ball class? To do this you can create an **init** method where you pass the variable into when you create the ball object.

```
class Ball:
  """ You can use the x and y variables anywhere in this class"""
  def __init__(self, x, y):
    self._x = x
    self._y = y

  def myMethod(self):
    print(self._x)
    print(self._y)

b1 = Ball(10, 20)
b1.myMethod()
```

**Or You could just pass the variables into the constructor**

```
x = 10
y = 10
b2 = Ball(x, y)
```