# Import variable from another .py without running the module

Tags: python, variables, import

I two .py files:

`file_1.py`

`file_2.py`

`file_1.py` contains code that will open an raster and split it into sections. Similar to creating a grid and clipping to each grid within QGIS. I have a variable `x` set as my file that I want to use "raster.tif". I would like import this variable into file_2.py. I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17255737/importing-variables-from-another-file) by @Ashwini Chaudhary (`import file_1` then `file_1.x`). The problem I am facing is when I run `file_2.py`, `file_1` is executing first. I simply want to access the variable and not execute the file. Is that possible to do?

Comment: You can't. You can put the code you don't want to run in an `if __name__ == "__main__":` guard, though. That is the idiomatic way of making a module that you can import or execute directly without the importing running the code

Comment: IOW: "I simply want to access the variable and not execute the file. Is that possible to do?" no, that isn't possible. *How could it be*?

Comment: Sorry what does IOW mean?

Comment: "in other words"

Comment: Basically, the *variable doesn't exist* until the module is executed, and there is no way to partially execute a module to extract the value of a particular variable. An `import` *always* executes the entire module. It has to. I closed this as a duplicate, you should read through the accepted answer and structure your modules using the `if __name__ == "__main__"` idiom

Comment: Okay, yes I understand. Thank you!

Answer (score -2):

This is not possible to do from the research i did. Sorry if i'm wrong