# is it possible to import a variable inside a function from one python script to another python script?

Tags: python, django

Apparently i have found out a way to import functions from one python script to another.

```
  from file_name.py import function_name
```

But is it possible to transfer variables as well.

Apologies cause I'm new to python.

Comment: Yes, you could, but it's a bad idea. it has been answered there.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17255737/importing-variables-from-another-file

Comment: Write a function which returns that variable and you can use it in other

Comment: just to be clear, the asterisk import is what is bad, because it can create confilcts with unknown variables imported. There is nothing wrong with cherry-picking variables, as long as you know whether you're redefining them after importing. ~ per sam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, there is no problem with that:

```
from file_name import function_name
print(function_name.variable_name)
```

Comment: i did try it, but i get an error saying ,AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'answer'

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can import variables too. You can import the variables the same way you import functions.

```
from file_name import variable_name
```

The `.py` isn't necessary. For the above statement to work the `file_name` has to be in the same directory as the file you are working on. Otherwise instead of `file_name` you can give the path to the file. i.e `C:\User\...\file_name`.