# Python Import Module

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-import

Recently started a new Python project.

I am resolving a import module error where I am trying to import modules from the same directory.

I was following the solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4142151/python-how-to-import-the-class-within-the-same-directory-or-sub-directory) but my situation is slightly different and as a result my script cannot run.

My project directory is as follows:

```
dir-parent
    ->dir-child-1
    ->dir-child-2
    ->dir-child-3
    ->__init__.py (to let python now that I can import modules from here)
    ->module1
    ->module2
    ->module3
    ->module4
    ->main.py
```

In my main.py script I am importing these module in the same directory as follows:

```
from dir-parent.module1 import class1
```

When I run the script using this method it throws a import error saying that there is no module named dir-parent.module1 (which is wrong because it exists).

I then change the import statement to:

```
from module1 import class1
```

and this seemed to resolve the error, however, the code I am working on has been in use for over 2.5 years and it has always imported modules via this method, plus in the code it refers to the dir-parent directory.

I was just wondering if there is something I am missing or need to do to resolve this without changing these import statements and legacy code?

EDIT: I am using PyCharm and am running off PyCharm

Comment: Is the directory containing `dir-parent` on the Python module search path?

Comment: You are probably executing main.py from within `dir-parent`. Try changing to one directory upwards and running `python -m dir_parent.main`. You can find more info in this excellent blog post: http://blog.habnab.it/blog/2013/07/21/python-packages-and-you/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep the code unchanged, I think you will have to add `dir-parent` to PYTHONPATH. For exemple, add the following on top of your main.py :

```
import os, sys

parent_dir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)) # get parent_dir path
sys.path.append(parent_dir)
```

Comment: Like so? parent_dir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(C:\dev\hpact\src)) complains that it is not valid syntax... I am using a windows machine

Comment: No, you can simply copy and paste : `__file__` is a variable referring to the current script.

Comment: 'parent_dir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))' 
sys.path.append("C:\dev\hpact\src\hpact") still complains of the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Python's import and pathing are a pain. This is what I do for modules that have a main. I don't know if pythonic at all.

```
# Add the parent directory to the path
CURRENTDIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)))
if CURRENTDIR not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(CURRENTDIR)
```