# how to import module in upper directory in python

Tags: python

I have several python modules in the project and I put them in different folders, for example,

```
pythonProject\folderA\modulex.py
pythonProject\folderB\moduley.py
pythonProject\commonModule\module1.py
```

I have `__init__.py` in each folder. 
In this situation, how can I import module1 into modulex?

Comment: How? Can you give an example? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Use relatively import

```
# in modulex
from ..commonModule import module1
```

Comment: See comments in the post above, it is still not working, can you help me?

Comment: You could not `run` the modulex isolate from the module. `from pythonProject.folderA import modulex` and use `modulex.xxx` to call what you want.

Comment: the problem is pythonproject cannot be found, the error is `ImportError: No module named 'pythonproject'`

Comment: do you have `__init__.py` in `pythonProject`?

Comment: Yes, I have it in pythonProject, is there any other files needed to make it a root folder for package?

Comment: import outside the `pythonproject` directory

Comment: what do you mean by outside the `pythonproject` directory?

Comment: `ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package`

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you have python packages (those folders that contain `__init__.py` files), you can import the modules like below

```
modulex.py
----------

from pythonproject.commonModule import module1
```

Try this, If the `pythonproject` is not defined by the tool, then you could use the relative addressing like below

```
from ..commonModule import module1
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, when I use the first method, it has the following error:    `from project.commonModule.Utils import Utils`   
`ImportError: No module named 'project'`

Comment: When I tried to use the second one, it has the following error: `SystemError: Parent module '' not loaded, cannot perform relative import`

Comment: For the first one, is there anyway to make the root folder special so that the root folder(project) can be recognized?

Comment: Question is how is your project structure? and What IDE do you use

Comment: Hey check out the 1st one you tried, you cannot use `from project.commonModule.Utils import Utils` because you are importing utils in utils, try this `from project.commonModule import Utils`

Comment: Oh, I have class Utils in module Utils.

Comment: The you have to use something like this `from project.commonModule.Utils import Utils as UClass` and then use `UClass.methods()` whenever needed

Comment: my project structure is `\project`, `\project\commonModule\module1.py`, `\project\otherFolder\otherModule.py`, and I want to import `module1` into `otherModule`. My IDE is pyCharm

Comment: Hey check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4142151/python-how-to-import-the-class-within-the-same-directory-or-sub-directory) out. Its very similar to your condition

Answer (score 0):

The best if all modules are in the same directory. In case any of them in different possible use of os.chdir(path). With os.chdir(path) method (https://docs.python.org/3.2/library/os.html) possible change working directory in your program.

```
import os
import modulex

#assume working directory is "pythonProject\folderA\"

os.chdir(r'pythonProject\commonModule\')
#now working directory is "pythonProject\commonModule\"

import module1
```

Comment: Although this might answer the question, it is always good to include an explanation to the code sample.