# Python access to Parent Directory

Tags: python

I have a file in the directory

```
app
   a
     Ulil.py
   b
     main.py
```

I want to import Ulil.py (at app\a) into main.py (at app\b).

How do i go about doing this. I need to move the file around as well so I don't want to put the entire path. I just to be in app\b and access only app\a. Folder name stays the same.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python: how to import the class within the same directory or sub directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4142151/python-how-to-import-the-class-within-the-same-directory-or-sub-directory)

Comment: You should be good like this `from a.Ulil import *`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the directory to sys.path:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert( 0, '../a' )
import Util
```

Answer (score 0):

First, create an empty file called `__init__.py` in **a**

Second,  in **main.py** in **b** import it using

```
import sys 
sys.path.insert( 0, '../' )
from a.Util import *
```

Comment: Tried that and it still says no module named a