# In Python: imports shenanigans (import subfolder.module in folder, use in subfolder/module2.py)

Tags: python, python-import

## Ok, this is not very clear at all. Allow me to rephrase.

**Quick note**: *"Solved" while writing this question. Will accept **answer** with inputs **regarding best practices**.*

**Original quick note**: *This is probably a duplicate. I apparently couldn't phrase the question well enough to fit this situation. My apologies if it is.*

First of all, to get you situated, here is my project's hierarchy as well as some relevant code:

```
Project/
├── main.py
└── lib
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── A.py
    ├── B.py
    └── C.py
```

`main.py`:

```
## Imports
from lib.A  import ClassA   as clA
from lib.B  import ClassB   as clB
from lib.C  import ClassC   as clC

#
# ... Some other code ...
#

a = clA()
b = clB()

a.add_ClB_Inst_Ref(b)
```

`A.py`:

```
## Imports
if __name__ == "__main__":
    from B  import ClassB   as clB
    from C  import ClassC   as clC

class ClassA:

    dict_Of_Weighted_ClB_Refs = {}
    #
    # ... Some other code (attributes, init, ...) ...
    #
    
    def add_ClB_Inst_Ref(self, ClB_Instance):
    
        if isinstance(ClB_Instance, clB):
            key = clB.ID

            if key in self.dict_Of_Weighted_ClB_Refs:
                self.dict_Of_Weighted_ClB_Refs[key] +=1
            else:
                self.dict_Of_Weighted_ClB_Refs[key] = 1
```

### Issue:

The program crashes in the `add_ClB_Inst_Ref` method when checking that the method's parameter is an instance of the ClassB object with the following error:

```
NameError: name 'clB' is not defined
```

*"Well"*, you might say, *"of course it crashes, the `A.py` files has never heard of that fancy `clB`!"*.
And, yes this may be the problem, but when I try to import it inside this file, replacing the imports section with this:

```
## Imports
from B  import ClassB   as clB
from C  import ClassC   as clC
```

I get the following error: `ImportError: No module named 'B'`

## Question:

How can I fix this? Your input on best practices would be most welcomed.

### Suspicions:

All this leads me to these hypothesis:

- Modules imported in a file at the root of the project aren't globally available for the duration of the program's execution.
- `import` searches a match from where the initial script has been executed. (**Note**: This lead me to double check that I had tried it this way `from lib.B import ClassB as clB` just like in the main file; turns out I hadn't and this works... I get the logic, but it seems rather counter intuitive. See answer below for details.)
- My project's architecture is flawed.

Comment: Possible duplicate. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4142151/python-how-to-import-the-class-within-the-same-directory-or-sub-directory

Comment: @Januson I don't think this qualifies as a duplicate. The question asked there concerns imports in _Folder/file.py_ of modules contained in _Folder/Subfolder/_, whereas my question is about this **combined** with using those same imported modules within files contained in _Folder/Subfolder/_ when executing the program from _Folder/file.py_ ...
Yes, you can probably see why I struggled with my search for duplicates ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in the question, here is what is needed to fix the issue of the unavailable module B in module A.

Simply replace the imports section in `A.py` with the following:

```
## Imports
if __name__ == "__main__":
    from B  import ClassB   as clB
    from C  import ClassC   as clC
else:
    from lib.B  import ClassB   as clB
    from lib.C  import ClassC   as clC
```

This doesn't seem like the best possible solution to me, as this means that each time the module is called from somewhere else than the `lib` folder, it assumes this "somewhere" is the project's root folder, which could lead to some serious conflicts.

#### Please write you own answer if you are able to provide a more general approach and/or best practices on this issue.

Comment: My understanding of best practices is that you should not use a module inside a package as an executable script at all. If you want to use a module to launch something, use Python's option to run a module (`python -m lib.A`). Then only use the package style imports. You can also do them as relative imports (i.e. `from .B import ...`).