# Importing class from another file

Tags: python, python-3.x

**Before you mark it as  duplicate** please read my problem:

I am trying to import a class from a file from a subdirectory

```
> main.py
> --->folder/
> ----->file.py
```

and in `file.py` i have a class imlpemented ( `Klasa`)
What have I tried:

putting in main.py:

```
from folder import file
from file import Klasa
```

I am getting the error:

> from file import Klasa
>
> ImportError: No module named 'file'

When I try to use just:

```
from folder import file
```

I get this error:

> tmp = Klasa()
>
> NameError: name 'Klasa' is not defined

I have put an empty `__init__.py` in the subfolder and it still does not work, and I have put in the `__init__.py`  : `from file import Klasa` and still doesnt work.

If main and file are in the same folder this work:

`from file import Klasa`

but i want them to be in separate files.

Can someone tell me what i am doing wrong?

Comment: import sys
sys.path.append(".")
from file import Klasa

Answer (score 341, accepted):

Your problem is basically that you never specified the right path to the file.

Try instead, from your main script:

```
from folder.file import Klasa
```

Or, with `from folder import file`:

```
from folder import file
k = file.Klasa()
```

Or again:

```
import folder.file as myModule
k = myModule.Klasa()
```

Comment: It works for me once I include an empty `__init__.py` file in the target directory containing class that is to be imported.

Comment: Simply "import Useful_Classes" (in file called "Useful_Classes.py") and then "from Useful_Classes import Hypothesis_Set" works. I added the magical/highly-nonintuitive/WTF !?!?! file "_ _ init _ _ .py" (no spaces in file name, spaces introduced to avoid unintentional bolding by HTML) to the directory. I also had to restart the kernel. There were many wrong turns on the route to this solution. This answer was one of the wrong turns. Python 3.10 in May 2022.