# Can't write to QTextBrowser when calling function from another file

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt

I have a python plugin where the `main.py` file displays a [QTextBrowser](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtextbrowser.html) and writes some text. This works fine.

I wrote a second file `anotherFile.py` which identifies the same QTextBrowser but cannot write any text to it. Perhaps it needs to take ownership, I'm not sure?

Here is the code used:

```
# main.py #
from Example_dockwidget import ExampleDockWidget
from anotherFile import anotherClass

class Example:
    def __init__(self, iface):
        self.iface = iface

    def function(self):
        self.dockwidget = ExampleDockWidget()
        self.dockwidget.show()

        textBrowser = self.dockwidget.textBrowser
        #textBrowser.setText('This works!')
        a = anotherClass(self)
        a.anotherFunction()
```

---

```
# anotherFile.py #
from Example_dockwidget import ExampleDockWidget

class anotherClass:
    def __init__(self, iface):
        self.iface = iface
        self.dockwidget = ExampleDockWidget()

    def anotherFunction(self):
        textBrowser = self.dockwidget.textBrowser
        textBrowser.setText('This does not work!')
        print 'Why?'
```

---

```
# Example_dockwidget.py #
FORM_CLASS, _ = uic.loadUiType(os.path.join(
    os.path.dirname(__file__), 'Example_dockwidget_base.ui'))

class ExampleDockWidget(QtGui.QDockWidget, FORM_CLASS):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(ExampleDockWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
```

Comment: I had a look at this post but it didn't help much: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45407616/calling-ui-objects-from-a-file-into-another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45407616/calling-ui-objects-from-a-file-into-another)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your two classes both create their own `ExampleDockWidget`.  Only one of them is shown (has its `show` method called) but there are two.

So it's not surprising that text sent to one does not appear on the other.  You need to arrange for your `anotherClass` object to obtain a reference to the other `ExampleDockWidget` so it can share the same one.

Comment: Thank you, your answer led me to a solution :)

Answer (score 0):

As [strubbly](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1295678/strubbly) mentioned, I need to reference the same `ExampleDockWidget` instead of creating separate versions. In the `anotherFile.py` file, I added an extra parameter to take in `ExampleDockWidget`:

```
class anotherClass:
    def __init__(self, iface, dockwidget):
        self.iface = iface
        self.dockwidget = dockwidget

    def anotherFunction(self):      
        textBrowser = self.dockwidget.textBrowser
        textBrowser.setText('This does not work!')
        print 'Why?'
```

And then inserted the reference in the `main.py` file:

```
def function(self):
    self.dockwidget = ExampleDockWidget()
    self.iface.addDockWidget(Qt.RightDockWidgetArea, self.dockwidget)
    self.dockwidget.show()

    textBrowser = self.dockwidget.textBrowser
    #textBrowser.setText('This works!')
    a = anotherClass(self.iface, self.dockwidget)
    a.anotherFunction()
```