# Imported a whole module called generalPy, but can't access classes

Tags: python, import

I have a module called **generalPy** and i want to access the python files in that folder. So i import it:`from generalPy import *`

The specific one i want to access is called fractions.py. It has a class with the name: **Fraction**. I try to create an instance of the class:`fract = Fraction()`.
Btw, it doesn't take any parameters. When i do this, i get an error:

```
NameError: name 'Fraction' is not defined
```

why cant i access that class when it is in the generalPy folder, and has been imported?

Comment: I understand genaralPy is a package, not a module, whereas fractions.py is a module within that package. Did you try fract = fractions.Fraction()?

Comment: try `fract = fractions.Fraction()`. Also, refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41276067/importing-class-from-another-file

Comment: Just tried. NameError: name 'fractions' is not defined

Answer (score 2):

```
from generalPy import *
```

This imports all the names from generalPy directly into the module’s namespace. Generally not a good idea as it leads to ‘namespace pollution’. If you find yourself writing this in your code, you would maybe be better off with just using:

```
import generalPy
```

Source and further reading: https://bytebaker.com/2008/07/30/python-namespaces/