# Import class form another python file Error

Tags: python, class, import

I have three file `.py`. `Main.py`, `one_file.py`, `second_file.py`.
In `one_file.py`, I have a class named `Create`.

In the `main.py` I have something like this:

```
import one_file
var = input("yes or no?")
if var == "yes":
    Create()
```

But I receive this error `NameError: name 'Create' is not defined`.
I also tried with `from one_file import Create` and `from . import one_file`
but it does not work anyway.

Code in `one_file.py`:

```
import random
class Create:
    def __init__(self):
        self.word()

    def word(self):
        word_list = ["hello", "word", "sun", "moon"]
        print("This is your word")
        print(random.choice(word_list))
```

Comment: `from one_file import Create` should work. What happens when you try that? What's the error message?

Comment: [Have you try this method This method works. I tried before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41276067/importing-class-from-another-file)

Comment: `one_file.Create()` should also work

Comment: if i try `from one_file import Create` ImportError: cannot import name Create

Comment: Can your post code of one_file.py

Comment: ah, I use python3

Comment: You want `from one_file import *`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to run the code from an imported library, you should first call the imported library.

```
import one_file
one_file.Create()
```

Otherwise, you can try

```
from one_file import Create
Create()
```