# Cannot import name python

Tags: python

Im trying to import Class1 into Class2 as below. Im getting the following error importError : cannot import name 'Class1'

```
class Class1:

  def __init__(self, list1, list2, list3):
    self.Var1= list1
    self.Var2= list2
    self.Var3= list3
    self.Var4= list4
    self.Var5= list5
    self.Var6= list6
    self.Var7= list7
```

Class 2 below

```
from Class1 import Class1
class Class2(Class1):
    def __init__(self,class_Class1):
         self.Var1= class_Class1.list1
         self.Var2= class_Class1.list2
         self.Var3 = class_Class1.list3
         self.Var4= class_Class1.list4
         self.Var5= class_Class1.list5
         self.Var6= class_Class1.list6
         self.Var7= class_Class1. list7
         self.A = A
         self.B = B
         self.C = C
```

Comment: what is the structure of your project (including filenames)? how do you run it?

Comment: Class1 is not a member of Class1. You can't import a module that isn't defined. If you had a Class1 member of Class1, then you could import it from Class1.

Comment: The .py files are all in the same folder(Calculation). I'm running though command line

Comment: @BoboDarph not accurate, if the filename is Class1 this should work

Comment: @Heredity what are the full names of the files? and what is the exact command that you are using?

Comment: @Hagai there is no reference to a file named Class1 in his post. Just two classes and a bad import statement.

Comment: right @BoboDarph, that's why I ask what are the filenames. If the files are called `Class1.py` and `Class2.py`, then this should work.

Comment: @Hagai The class names match the file names, im just using #! C:\Soft\Python\python.exe inside the file and dragging the file into the command console

Comment: @Heredity so they are called `Class1.py` and `Class2.py`, right? you still haven't answered my question how exactly you run it. specifically - what is the working directory from which you are running it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41276067/importing-class-from-another-file

Answer (score 0):

it should be:

```
from <file_name_of_class1> import Class1
```

so if the file name is `Class1.py` the line you wrote should be correct. please check your file names and tell us, also you might need to have an empty file named: `__init__.py` in order to import.
check out this guide:
[guide on import in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4142151/how-to-import-the-class-within-the-same-directory-or-sub-directory#4142178)

Comment: Yes the file names match the Class names(double checked by copying the names into each other), I tried adding a empty __init__.py and get the same error. I am able to import other classes into Class1