# How can I properly load a Python class in my project?

Tags: python

My older structure is:

[image]

In a file, I'm doing:

```
from CodeModel import CodeModel

codemodel = CodeModel.CodeModel()
```

But that seems redundant. Is there a cleaner way to import `CodeModel` without having to do `CodeModel.CodeModel()`?

Comment: `from CodeModel.CodeModel import CodeModel` ;-)

Comment: Or put `from .CodeModel import CodeModel` in your `__init__.py`.  Then `from CodeModel import CodeModel` from outside the package will import the class.  (You should probably give the packages, modules, and classes different names though, or it quickly becomes very confusing)

Comment: Can you put this as an answer and I will accept?

Comment: Why is `CodeModel.py` even in a package called `CodeModel`? There seems to be nothing else in it. Just remove that package.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean @mkrieger1. I want to create a class called `CodeModel`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Importing class from another file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41276067/importing-class-from-another-file)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from CodeModel.CodeModel import CodeModel
```

but you should think of different packages&modules structure because it may indeed be redundant.

If you have multiple (but not **really** many) models, think of creating modules.py with CodeModel and other model classes. Simplify things if possible (adequatly to project's size).

```
from models import CodeModel
```

seems better, doesn't it?

Another option would be

```
from .CodeModel import CodeModel
```

inside `__init__.py` of CodeModel package, already mentioned in the comment by Patrick Haugh.