# Python: file location when opened inside a class that is used in other modules

Tags: python, python-3.x

Suppose I have a file structure like this one:

```
test
    mammals
        Wolf.py
        wolfname.txt
    Zoo.py
```

And inside `Wolf.py` I have:

```
class Wolf:
    def __init__(self):
        with open('wolfname.txt', 'r') as fileobj:
            self.name = fileobj.read()
        print(self.name)

wolf = Wolf()
```

If I call it from inside `Wolf.py`, it works fine. If I call it from inside `Zoo.py`, it gives a `FFileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'wolfname.txt'`
 error.

What is the way to fix it without resolving to absolute paths? I might want to use the `Wolf` class from some other new package in the future as well.

I use this import inside the Zoo:

```
from mammals.Wolf import Wolf

wolf = Wolf()
```

**EDIT**: I've made this repl.it to show it online: https://repl.it/repls/DrearyGrizzledMicroscope

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get the full path of the current file's directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3430372/how-do-i-get-the-full-path-of-the-current-files-directory)

Comment: What relative path did you try? If mammals is in the same folder as Zoo.py then the path from Zoo.py should be mammals/wolfname.txt

Comment: @PierreV. `import os
os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))` would give me location of Zoo, wouldn't it? `C://.../ProjectRoot/` (I'd also want to run this program on Linux in the future). However, I'd have to hardcode something like `if s.endsWith("ProjectRoot"): go to mammals`? Then if I'd like to use `Wolf` in 10 other modules each located in different folder... Then what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resorted to using this:

```
class Wolf:
    def __init__(self, path = ''):
        with open(path + 'wolfname.txt', 'r') as fileobj:
            self.name = fileobj.read()
        print(self.name)
```

and in Zoo:

```
from mammals import Wolf

print("inside Main.py")
wolf = Wolf.Wolf("mammals/")
```

Thus in different files I can pass different relative paths.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of that; do this:

```
from mammals import Wolf
```

Then you can access Wolf class by `Wolf.Wolf`

Comment: Thank you, this worked: `import mammals` and later `wolf = Wolf.Wolf()`

Comment: @parsecer I just accessed a module from package that was in my current directory. See more at https://stackoverflow.com/a/7948504/9134528

Comment: Sorry, it didn't work... Tried bot `wolf = Wolf.Wolf()` and `wolf = Wolf()`

Comment: @parsecer `from mammals.Wolf import Wolf ` will work too. If doesn't, there must be some other issue.

Comment: The package does get accessed. If I make `print("inside Wolf")` the first line in `Wolf.py` then when running from `Zoo` it would print it, but then, when it tries to `wolf = Wolf()` it would print `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'wolfname.txt'
`

Comment: @parsecer The error is saying that it couldn't found the file 'wolfname.txt'. Try this: 'mammals/wolfname.txt'

Comment: Then it works from inside `Zoo.py` but not from inside `Wolf.py`. And if I create a folder `house` and put `HousePets.py` inside and try to `wolf = Wolf()` it wouldn't find the file either.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204733/discussion-between-vicrobot-and-parsecer).

Answer (score 0):

Try renaming the 'wolf.py' file or Wolf classname into something else.

It will maybe solve the `FileNotFoundError` because the names are the same.

Otherwise: maybe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41276151/12488560) will help you out?