# How to import a class from another file in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Im new to python and have looked at various stack overflow posts. i feel like this should work but it doesnt. How do you import a class from another file in python?
This folder structure

```
src/example/ClassExample
src/test/ClassExampleTest
```

I have this class

```
class ClassExample:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def helloWorld(self):
        return "Hello World!"
```

I have this test class

```
import unittest
from example import ClassExample

class ClassExampleTest(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_HelloWorld(self):
        hello = ClassExample()
        self.assertEqual("Hello World!", hello.helloWorld())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

When the unit test runs the object is None:

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'helloWorld'

What's wrong with this? How do you import a class in python?

Comment: Try `import example; print(example)` to see you actually imported the `example` module, not other module that is in python  import path.

Comment: I don't see how `hello` can be None.

Comment: The code shown here looks reasonable.  Make sure you are importing from the correct file.  Change file names to verify you are not reading from the wrong file.

Comment: when I do what @falsetru says it prints "<module 'example' from '/Users/thomas/.pyenv/versions/3.6.1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/example/__init__.py'>"

Comment: It sounds like the site-package example module actually has a "ClassExample" class.  What are the odds??

Comment: Are those directories or Is that `src/example/ClassExample.py` and `src/test/ClassExampleTest.py`? Is there some other install going on? Your test shouldn't see `example` as a module as it stands in your source tree. Its behaving as through there is an `example.py` with a function called `CaseExample` in your test directory.

Comment: Okay, so you've installed this package before test and are getting `example` from python's site-packages. There is also an `__init__.py`. `from example import ClassExample` is importing "ClassExample" from `__init__.py` 's namespace. So what is in `__init__.py`?

Comment: @tdelaney nothing is in __init__.py

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Importing class from another file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41276067/importing-class-from-another-file)

Comment: How do you execute `ClassExampleTest.py` (and in what directory)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're using Python 3, then imports are absolute by default. This means that `import example` will look for an absolute package named `example`, somewhere in the [module search path](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path).

So instead, you probably want a [relative import](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#package-relative-imports). This is useful when you want to import a module that is *relative* the module doing the importing. In this case:

```
from ..example.ClassExample import ClassExample
```

I'm assuming that your folders are Python [packages](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages), meaning that they contain `__init__.py` files. So your directory structure would look like this.

```
src
|-- __init__.py
|-- example
|   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- ClassExample.py
|-- test
|   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- ClassExampleTest.py
```

Comment: I tried this. I get: `TypeError: 'module' object is not callable`

Comment: Ah. Do you have your class inside a *file* named `ClassExample.py`?

Comment: Relative import doesn't work for scripts (like this unit test script), only for packages and modules. Scripts aren't in packages so there is nothing to be relative to.

Comment: Yes. That is it Nikolas

Comment: @Dan, in that case, you need `from .example.ClassExample import ClassExample`

Comment: I think there is something else that is messed up because if I change the name of the folder example. It doesnt even find it.

Comment: @tdelaney OP lists a directory structure starting with `src`. I assume this is a package structure. But you're right; I'll clarify this assumption.

Comment: @Dan I updated my answer to clarify some assumptions I'm making about your directory structure.

Comment: Your import worked however I had delete the example folder from .pyenv/versions/3.6.1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/example ... I dont know how it got there in the first place 

Comment: @Dan That's odd... the point of relative imports is that whatever is in your `site-packages` shouldn't be considered in the first place.

Comment: Do you know how I can avoid that problem in the future? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225070/discussion-between-nikolas-stevenson-molnar-and-dan).