# How to import py files into a main python script?

Tags: python, python-import

so I have a data cleaning project that looks something like this:

```
import math
import os
import pandas as pd
import math


class CustomDataFrame():
    code    
class CustomDataFrameItem():
    code
class Util():
    code

class Program():
    code

if __name__ == "__main__":
    p = Program()
    p.run()
```

However, I wish to put the 4 classes into individual py files and have a main file with only

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
        p = Program()
        p.run()
```

But I am not sure how to call all the class files if I separate them.

Can you show me what to do? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Importing class from another file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41276067/importing-class-from-another-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I highly recommend checking out the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html) or [a tutorial](https://realpython.com/python-import/) to learn about the `import` command.

You can split them into individual files and import them if they are all in the same directory without any problems.

This answer assumes your directory has the following structure:

```
.
| - file1.py
| - file2.py
| - ...etc
| - main.py
```

If you wish to nest your directories, see the other answer. Their answer covers how to use `__init__.py` to take care of that.

If you have the classes defined in individual files, you only need to import standard libraries that are required for that script. For example, if `CustomDataFrame` required `RequiredModule1` and `RequiredModule2` but not `matplotlib`, you would write this in `file1.py`.

`file1.py`

```py
import RequiredModule1
import RequiredModule2
#etc
class CustomDataFrame():
    code
```

You can either separate them out into individual files, or group modules together into a single file and import each of them.
`file2.py`

```py
class CustomDataFrameItem():
    code 
class Program():
    code
```

`main.py`

```py
from file1 import CustomDataFrame
from file2 import CustomDataFrameItem, Program
if __name__ == "__main__":
    p = Program()
    p.run()
```

Note that you do not put the file extension `.py` on the `from fileX import xxx`. The `.py` is inferred by the interpreter.

Answer (score 1):

In the case of file structure:

```
-main.py
-folder_1
 |---file1.py
 |---file2.py
```

It can be done by specifying the empty `__init__.py` file in the folder containing all the `.py` files.

which would look like this:

```
-main.py
-folder_1
 |---file1.py
 |---file2.py
 |---__init__.py
```