# importing function works, importing class doesn't

Tags: python

When I import a function it runs the code no problem, but if I import a class it doesn't work. It says ImportError: cannot import name 'Y' and I have tried it on sublime text, and command prompt. 
If I import a function it works.

```
from testing2 import x
x()
#testing2.py has:
def x():
    print("It worked")
```

If I import a class it doesn't work.

```
from testing2 import Y
Y().x()

#testing2 has:

class Y:
    def x(self):
        print("It worked")
```

Comment: Both worked for me. Did you name something else as `Y` below class `Y`?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with code. You may saving in some path and trying to access from another.

Comment: It works for me

Comment: This is the only code in the files, and I am using only these same files. I will successfully import a function, then erase everything and rewrite it with a class, and it brings an error when importing a class.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4142151/how-to-import-the-class-within-the-same-directory-or-sub-directory

Comment: @ whackamadoodle3000 I have tried creating a "__init__.py" file, adding a "." in front of .testing2 and it still didn't work. Possibly I need to uninstall python then reinstall it I don't know.

Comment: Issues like this are rarely to do with your installation of Python.  Have you tried a completely blank directory; create your Python file with your class and function in it; cd to that directory, open the console, type :'import <module> , and the use dir on the module - check that the function and class are both visible in the dir output.

Comment: @ Tony Suffolk thanks for the advice, for whatever reason when I made a new folder in a completely different directory it worked.. Do you have advice on keywords for a google search on why this is?

Comment: @ Tony Suffolk the original is working now too, so it was like trying it in a different folder snapped my computer back into shape or something.