# Python "ImportError: No module named 'x'

Tags: python, import, python-import

Strike this - turns out it was something completely unrelated.  (also, ".py" suffixes)

my file structure is as so:

```
src /
  | main.py
  | filehandler.py
```

my main.py is failing at the line:

```
import filehander.py
```

with the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 7, in <module>
    import filehander
ImportError: No module named 'filehander'
```

Why is python failing to do the simple task of importing a file in the same directory so badly?

Comment: You don't import files, you import modules. The file system is just an implementation detail. [You think that's air you're breathing, now](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CWaxF8jlnm0)?

Comment: `import filehander.py` is wrong. you dont write .py in import. `import filehander` is right syntax.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to import the class within the same directory or sub directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4142151/how-to-import-the-class-within-the-same-directory-or-sub-directory)

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to write extension of a file while importing. Just use `import filehandler`

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1. `import filehandler` not `import filehandler.py`
2. You must be in the `/src` folder when you run the program. The path is always WRT the current folder.

Comment: I am.  When I run "ls" I see both files.

Comment: In that case you should not have a problem ... Are you running your python  program using `python main.py`? Or are you running it using Spyder or something similar?

Answer (score 0):

Check the [working directory](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5137507/8375783) of your main.py. If you are using an IDE and you moved the file from a directory to an another then the 'configuration' of the file may remained the same and it tries to run where it initially was.

And like others mentioned, use `import filehandler`, not 'filehandler.py'

Answer (score 0):

This error will also occur when there is a syntax error in the imported class. call the class directly to check no errors are returned by pyton:

```
python.exe filehander.py
```