# Module not found error (imutils.paths)

Tags: python, opencv3.0

**This is the code i'm trying to run on an virtual environment in python3.6. I use ubuntu newest version 17.10, I run the code as  python3 gather_annotations.py**

```
import numpy as np  
import cv2 
import argparse  
from imutils.paths import list_images
from selectors import BoxSelector  
#parse arguments
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()  
ap.add_argument("-d","--dataset",required=True,help="path to images dataset...")  
ap.add_argument("-a","--annotations",required=True,help="path to save annotations...")  
ap.add_argument("-i","--images",required=True,help="path to save images")  
args = vars(ap.parse_args())  
#annotations and image paths  
annotations = []  
imPaths = []  
#loop through each image and collect annotations  
for imagePath in list_images(args["dataset"]):  
    #load image and create a BoxSelector instance  
    image = cv2.imread(imagePath)  
    bs = BoxSelector(image,"Image")  
    cv2.imshow("Image",image)  
    cv2.waitKey(0)  
    #order the points suitable for the Object detector  
    pt1,pt2 = bs.roiPts  
    (x,y,xb,yb) = [pt1[0],pt1[1],pt2[0],pt2[1]]  
    annotations.append([int(x),int(y),int(xb),int(yb)])  
    imPaths.append(imagePath)  
#save annotations and image paths to disk  
annotations = np.array(annotations)  
imPaths = np.array(imPaths,dtype="unicode")  
np.save(args["annotations"],annotations)  
np.save(args["images"],imPaths)
```

[**And I get the following errors**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZPdji.png)

**I have this Folder named '2' where I have all the scripts and other folder named selectors where there is 2 scripts init and box_selector**

- 2(folder)
- ----selectors/
- ------------_ *init* _.py
- ------------box_selector.py
- ----detector.py
- ----gather_annotations.py
- ----test.py
- ----train.py

How can I fix that, in the post where I got the code from says something about 'relative imports' but i couln't fix it, thank you.

Comment: How do we reproduce the error? Also, what is your working directory and where is it relative to the module you'd import?

Comment: i run the code in terminal as $ python3 gather_annotations.py, and get the error in the picture, the module im trying to run is box_selector from the script gather_annotations

Comment: Welcome to SO. I recommend you edit your question to put the error in the question as text rather that a screen grab image. An image makes it a pain to read making it less likely you'll get help.

Comment: I think the title can be misleading. Clearly the error has nothing to do with `from imutils.paths import list_images` but with `from selectors import BoxSelector`. Besides it is a `ModuleNotFoundError` according to your attached photo, not "Imutils error".

Comment: There's no `BoxSelector` but only `box_selector` under `selectors` directory. I think that's why your are getting the error.

Comment: I had some trouble adding the error as text so I just took a screenshot(sorry) and ytu yes you are right I didnt know to post the error i'll change it right know

Comment: there is a class named BoxSelector in the box_selector.py, my guess is that it calls the function _ _ init _ _ which only have this code ''from box_selector import BoxSelector''

Comment: I fix it !!!! i literally just added a  "." to the _ _ init _ _ .py so instead of havin --from box_selector import BoxSelector-- I did this --from .box_selector import BoxSelector-- and it worked !! python 3 module is very different than python 2 thank you all :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use . notation to access a file inside a folder..

so

```
from folder.python_file import ClassOrMethod
```

in your case

```
from selectors.box_selector import BoxSelector
```

Having`__init__.py` in the selectors folder is crucial to making this work.

You can as many folders as you like and can access as follows but each folder has to contain an `__init__.py` to work

```
from folder.folder1.folder2.python_file import ClassOrMethod
```

Comment: thank you i saw this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4142151/how-to-import-the-class-within-the-same-directory-or-sub-directory and i fix it right away XD

Comment: Glad to hear it.. I can remember having the same problem!!

Answer (score 0):

One possible area of confusion is that there is a different python library called "selectors" which is DIFFERENT from the selectors of this code example.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/selectors.html

I ended up rename "selectors" (including the directory) of this example to "boxselectors"

This example is from http://www.hackevolve.com/create-your-own-object-detector/