# How to import from the same module

Tags: python-3.x, python-import

So, this is my project tree:

```
|--project
|  |--script.py
|  |--Module/
|  |  |--__init__.py
|  |  |--src/
|  |  |  |--__init__.py
|  |  |  |--cell.py ==> class Cell
|  |  |  |--map.py  ==> class Map
|  |  |--test/
|  |  |  |--__init__.py
|  |  |  |--test.py
```

I'm having problems to import Map and Cell classes from test.py

I have tried using:

```
from Module.src.map import Map
from .src.map import Map
```

and neither of those works, any idea on how to import in this case and why the two latest import statements doesn't work?

Comment: You should try just `from Module import Map`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to import the class within the same directory or sub directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4142151/how-to-import-the-class-within-the-same-directory-or-sub-directory)