# How to import a import in the same folder / directory?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How do I import a library within the same folder / directory?

I tried using [this answer / solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4142151/how-to-import-the-class-within-the-same-directory-or-sub-directory), but Python throws this error:

```
user@computer:~/program$ python3 __init__.py
  File "__init__.py", line 102
    import .get_len
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
user@computer:~/program$ pwd
/home/user/program
```

```py
Python 3.5.3 (default, Sep 27 2018, 17:25:39) 
[GCC 6.3.0 20170516] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> exit()
```

Note: `user` and `computer` are not real names.

```py
100|        if args.mode == 'get-len':
101|            try:
102|                import .get_len
103|            except ImportError as error:
104|                msg = str(error)
```

## File Tree

```
program_folder
| __init__.py
| get_len.py
| get_chart.py
| get_geo.py
```

Comment: `from . import get_len`

Comment: It gives another error:

Comment: It gives another error:
  File "__init__.py", line 206, in <module>
    from . import get_len
SystemError: Parent module '' not loaded, cannot perform relative import

Comment: Is your path set up right?

Comment: I ran python3 from the directory __init__.py was located.

Comment: Run from one folder up. The driver script should be next to the package, not in it. Unless you run with `python -m`