# Package Object Oriented python

Tags: python-3.x, python-packaging

I am trying one demo, where I am using modules there are three code files and bellow is the structure of the codes

```
--Main Dir 
--packages
          - __init__.py
          - Input.py 
          - Calculation.py
          - Add.py 
 -main.py
```

****init**.py** is empty

**Input.py**

```
class Input:

def __init__(self):
    print("input is initialized")
```

**Calculation.py**

```
import Input

class Calculator:
    def __init__(self):
        ip = Input.Input()
        print("calculator is itisilised")
```

**Add.py**

```
import Calculation

class Add:
    def __init__(self):
        cal = Calculation.Calculator()
        print("add class is initialsed")
```

**main.py**

```
from packages import Add

class main:
    def __int__(self):
        print("main is initialsed")
        objadd = Add.Add()

main_obj = main()
```

but I am getting bellow Error

```
in Add.py    
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Calculation'
```

Comment: well yes, why do you assume `Calculation` to be in the path?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to import the class within the same directory or sub directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4142151/how-to-import-the-class-within-the-same-directory-or-sub-directory)