# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named ten_project.ten_app.models

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

I just creating a simple backend and everything working fine until I create this python **filepopulate_fake_script.py** when I'm trying to run this it's showing **ModuleNotFoundError: No module named** And I've already checked other similar questions but unable to solve. Please help me to fix this. And  you can see all files in here https://github.com/crajygemer/Django_Stuff/tree/master/ten_project

```
import os
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'ten_project.settings')

import django
django.setup()

# Fake Pop Script
import random
from ten_project.ten_app.models import AccessRecord, Webpage, Topic
from faker import Faker
fakegen = Faker()
topics = ['Search', 'Social', 'Marketplace', 'News', 'Games']

# call Topic Model
def add_topic():
    t = Topic.objects.get_or_create(top_name=random.choice(topics))[0]
    t.save()
    return t

# call rest of Models
def populate(N=5):

    for entry in range(N):

        # get the topic for the entry
        top = add_topic()

        # add fake data for each entry
        fake_url = fakegen.url()
        fake_name = fakegen.company()
        fake_date = fakegen.date()

        # fake entry for webpage model
        webpg = Webpage.objects.get_or_create(
            topics, url=fake_url, name=fake_name)[0]

        # fake entry for access record
        acc_rec = AccessRecord.objects.get_or_create(
            name=webpg, date=fake_date)[0]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('Run Fake Script')
    populate(20)
    print('Run Successfully.')
```

Comment: Please show the complete, exact error message.

Comment: Hello @KarlKnechtel Thanks for your reply. Please check I added the Error Details.

Comment: I see. Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time help?

Comment: Not really @KarlKnechtel :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Django absolute imports works in respect to the *manage.py*. You have your *manage.py* in *ten_project* directory so that means your import should be

```
from ten_app.models import AccessRecord, Webpage, Topic
```

Comment: That's the 1st one I was applied @mursalin

Comment: check if your project root is there in your system path

Comment: Yes I've checked seems Ok

Comment: can you change your import as I suggested and update your question with error report?

Comment: If you are using Atom or VS CODE then you won't see the Error but if you use Pycharm then Pycharm going to show you an error that Dir not getting called properly. Have a look at this screenshot **http://prntscr.com/t6r0sq**

Comment: that's the correct way to call dir `ten_project.ten_app.models import AccessRecord, Webpage, Topic` but still not working

Comment: Thats because pycharm is not configured properly and doesn't know your project root. your question **is not** about IDE configuration. Does it give any error if you run your script?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216700/discussion-between-mursalin-and-just-dont-be-user123).

Comment: Problem Solved. Thanks to @mursalin 
problem were in misspell that's totally funny. Here is the updated line
`webpg = Webpage.objects.get_or_create(topic=top, url=fake_url, name=fake_name)[0]`

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a **ModuleNotFoundError** because your script cannot import this:

`from ten_project.ten_app.models import AccessRecord, Webpage, Topic`

You should take a look at this: [How to import the class within the same directory or sub directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4142151/how-to-import-the-class-within-the-same-directory-or-sub-directory).

Comment: That's the 2nd one I was applied

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "populate_fake_script.py", line 9, in <module>
    from eleven_project.eleven_app.models import Topic, AccessRecord, Webpage
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'eleven_project.eleven_app'
`