# How to import python module from same folder?

Tags: python, import

With python 3.7 I am trying to import functions which are defined in a module file. This module file is named `mytool.py` and contains

```
def foo():
    return 42
```

Following the solution I found on [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4142151/how-to-import-the-class-within-the-same-directory-or-sub-directory) I have the main code `mycode.py` as follows:

```
from . import mytool
```

which yields an error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mycode.py", line 3, in <module>
    from . import mytool
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

Is there a way to fix this as short and concise as possible, without having to add to `sys.path`?

Comment: Did you try `import mytool`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`from mytool import foo`

or

`import mytool`