# How to relative import a script in another folder at the same directory level?

Tags: python, python-3.x, relative-import

So i want to import a script in other folder on the same directory level.

It's like this:

```
project
   ├── src
         ├── basic - __init__.py
         └── physics - __init__.py
```

I want to import a class from basic file, into the physics file.

**Edit**

I settled to just rename this files to basic.py and physics.py and placed them in the same folder so the directory looks like this now:

```
project
   ├── src
         ├── basic.py
         └── physics.py
```

Comment: Could you please edit the directory diagram? It's hard to see what is where. Is physics folder in basic folder?

Comment: @tornikeo I edited it. its on the same level they are both in the src folder

Comment: Just add the regular `__init__.py` file to basic folder and then type `from .basic import MyClass`. Does that help? Also add the `__init__.py` file to src folder.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to import the class within the same directory or sub directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4142151/how-to-import-the-class-within-the-same-directory-or-sub-directory)

Comment: @tornikeo I solved it but it was a bit of misunderstanding. Thanks for help anyways.